# Shortest Pangrammatic Window

Tags: code-golf, string

A pangram is a sentence or excerpt which contains all twenty-six letters of the alphabet, as is demonstrated in [this code golf challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/is-it-a-pangram). However, [a pangrammatic *window*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangrammatic_window) is a pangram in the form of some segment of text, which may end or begin halfway through a word, found somewhere within a larger work. These naturally occur everywhere, being proper subsets of true pangrams, so just verifying if something contains a pangrammatic window would be boring and also it was previously done.

So, we're interested in finding the smallest one there is in a given piece of text based on its letter length! In the shortest possible code in bytes, of course, to fit the theme.

### Rules and Guidelines

- Receive a string as the input and return  the string of the smallest pangrammatic window in the input if there is one. If there is not, return either a Boolean False or an empty string.
- Whether a string is a pangrammatic window or not is case-insensitive and only depends on the 26 letters, not any punctuation or numbers or other odd symbols.
- Similarly, a pangrammatic window's **letter length** is the total number of how many appearances of *letters* occur in it alone, and not simply the number of every character. The returned value must be smallest based on this count. We're linguists, after all, not programmers.
- An output of a pangrammatic window must, however, must be an exact substring of the input, containing the same capitalization and punctuation, etc.
- If there are multiple shortest pangrammatic windows of the same letter length, return any one of them.

### Test Cases

```
'This isn't a pangram.'
==> False

'Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).'
==> 'Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ig'

'"The five boxing wizards jump quickly." stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" he shouted to the heavens.'
==> 'ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

Comment: "the total number of how many appearances of letters occur in it alone" can you clarify?

Comment: That was actually meant to be more clarified from the version of it I originally posted in the sandbox, but oh well. I mean the count of letters, a-z, A-Z, ignoring any other characters. So, 'Foot!' would have a letter length of 4.

Comment: For the last test case, why isn't `The five boxing wizards jump quickly` returned?

Comment: For the second case, are you allowed the space preceding the `Q`? It doesn't add to the letter count.

Comment: @muddyfish Because it has 31 letters, whereas the expected output has only 26.

Comment: Theoretically, yeah, you could leave the space before the 'Q.'

Comment: Nice first question!

Comment: In the same vein as Neil, is ' . "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' acceptable for the last test case?

Comment: Yep. No reason it shouldn't be. Taking the "true" minimum's in the *spirit* of the question, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 6):

### Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>16</s> 14 bytes

```
hol@GNf!-GrT0.:
```

Explanation:

```
             .: - substrings of input()
      f!-GrT0   - filter to ones which contain the alphabet
 ol@GN          - sort by number of alphabetical chars
h               - ^[0]

      f!-GrT0   - filter(lambda T:V, substrings)
          rT0   -    T.lower()
        -G      -   alphabet-^
       !        -  not ^

 o              - sort(^, lambda N:V)
   @GN          -   filter_presence(alphabet, N)
  l             -  len(^)
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=hol%40GNf!-GrT0.%3A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22This+isn%27t+a+pangram.%22%0A%22Everyone+knows+about+that+infamous+Quick-Brown-Fox+%28the+one+who+jumped+over+some+lazy+ignoramus+of+a+dog+so+many+years+ago%29.%22%0A%27%22The+five+boxing+wizards+jump+quickly.%22+stated+Johnny%2C+before+beginning+to+recite+the+alphabet+with+a+bunch+of+semicolons+in+the+middle.+%22ABCDEFGHI%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3BJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!%22+he+shouted+to+the+heavens.%27&debug=0)

When there isn't a correct solution, the program exits with an error with no output to stdout.

Comment: You seem to not have updated the code in the first code block. Also `!-GrT0` is shorter for the filter condition, I believe. I also think you do need the `l` to make the sort work properly.

Comment: Oh, I misspoke, I meant the link. In your link you still have the `l`, and without it [you get different results](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ho%40GNfg.%7BrT0G.%3A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Everyone+knows+about+that+infamous+Quick-Brown-Fox+%28the+one+who+jumped+over+some+lazy+ignoramus+of+a+dog+so+many+years+ago%29.%22&debug=0). I believe the problem is repeated letters, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: So it does matter - and thanks for the optimization!

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth - 22 bytes

\o/ FGITW!

```
h+ol@GrNZf}GS{rTZ.:z)k
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=h%2Bol%40GrNZf%7DGS%7BrTZ.%3Az%29k&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=This+isn%27t+a+pangram.%0AEveryone+knows+about+that+infamous+Quick-Brown-Fox+%28the+one+who+jumped+over+some+lazy+ignoramus+of+a+dog+so+many+years+ago%29.%0A%22The+five+boxing+wizards+jump+quickly.%22+stated+Johnny%2C+before+beginning+to+recite+the+alphabet+with+a+bunch+of+semicolons+in+the+middle.+%22ABCDEFGHI%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3B%3BJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ%21%22+he+shouted+to+the+heavens.&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>139</s> <s>138</s> 136 bytes

```js
s=>[r=l="",...s].map((_,b,a)=>a.map((c,i)=>i>b&&(t+=c,z=parseInt(c,36))>9&&(v++,n+=!m[z],m[z]=n<26||l&&v>l||(r=t,l=v)),t=m=[],v=n=0))&&r
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil!*

### Indented

```js
var solution =

s=>
  [r=l="",...s].map((_,b,a)=> // b = index of start of window to check
    a.map((c,i)=>
      i>b&&(
        t+=c,
        z=parseInt(c,36)
      )>9&&(
        v++,
        n+=!m[z],
        m[z]=
          n<26||
          v>l&&l||(
            r=t,
            l=v
          )
      ),
      t=m=[],
      v=n=0
    )
  )
  &&r
```

```html
<textarea cols="70" rows="6" id="input">Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).</textarea><br /><button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Can you not use `[r=l="",...s].map((_,b,a)=>`?

Comment: @Neil Thanks, I always forget about the third parameter in the `map` function.

Comment: I think @edc65 can beat this though, I merged the code for his exploded substrings with that for his pangram tester and ended up with a 134 byte function.

Comment: My best is 142 so far

Comment: Sadly I didn't think to save it and my PC crashed so now I don't know what I had; the best I can do now is 138 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 100 bytes

Returns nil if no window is found.

```
->s{r=0..s.size
(r.map{|i|s[i,r.find{|j|(?a..?z).all?{|c|s[i,j]=~/#{c}/i}}||0]}-['']).min_by &:size}
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v2+, 218 bytes

```
param($a)$z=@{};(0..($b=$a.length-1)|%{($i=$_)..$b|%{-join$a[$i..$_]}})|%{$y=$_;$j=1;65..90|%{$j*=$y.ToUpper().IndexOf([char]$_)+1};if($j){$z[($y-replace'[^A-Za-z]').Length]=$y}}
($z.GetEnumerator()|sort Name)[0].Value
```

Yeah, so substring manipulation (there aren't any built-ins) isn't really PowerShell's strong suit...

We take input `param($a)` and set a new empty hashtable `$z`. This will be our storage of candidate pangrammatic substrings.

Using a slight modification of my code from [Exploded Substrings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78712/42963), we construct *all* substrings of the input. Yep, even one-character punctuation-only substrings. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), not [fastest-code](/questions/tagged/fastest-code). ;-)

All of those substrings are encapsulated in parens and piped into another loop with `|%{...}`. We temporarily set `$y` to our current substring, set a helper counter `$j`, and start another loop `65..90|%{...}`, conveniently over the ASCII char codes for capital letters. Each inner loop, we take `$y`, make it all uppercase, and pull out the `.IndexOf` that particular char. Since this will return `-1` if not found, we `+1` the result before multiplying it into `$j`. This ensures that if any one character isn't found, `$j` will equal zero.

Which is exactly what the `if` is all about. If `$j` is non-zero, that means that every letter was found at least once in the substring `$y`, so we need to add that to our candidate pool. We do so by taking `$y` and `-replace`ing every non-letter with nothing, which gets us the letter-length of that substring. We use that as the index into hashtable `$z` and store `$y` at that index. This has the quirk of overwriting substrings of the same letter-length with the one that occurs "furthest" in the original string, but that's allowed by the rules, since we're only concerned about letter-length.

Finally, we need to sort through `$z` and pull out the smallest. We have to use the `.GetEnumerator` call in order to sort on the *objects inside* `$z`, then `sort` those on `Name` (i.e., the length index from above), selecting the `[0]`th one (i.e., the shortest), and outputting its `.Value` (i.e., the substring). If no such substring fits, this will toss an error (`Cannot index into a null array`) when it tries to index into `$z`, and output nothing, which is falsey in PowerShell. (the third test case below has an explicit cast as `[bool]` to show this)

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts> .\golfing\shortest-pangrammatic-window.ps1 '"The five boxing wizards jump quickly." stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" he shouted to the heavens.'
ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" 

PS C:\Tools\Scripts> .\golfing\shortest-pangrammatic-window.ps1 'Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).'
Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ig

PS C:\Tools\Scripts> [bool](.\golfing\shortest-pangrammatic-window.ps1 "This isn't a pangram.")
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing\shortest-pangrammatic-window.ps1:2 char:1
+ ($z.GetEnumerator()|sort Name)[0].Value
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

False
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>171, 167, 163, 157</s>, 149 bytes.

Saved 4 bytes thanks to DSM.
Saved 8 bytes thanks to RootTwo.

```
lambda x,r=range:min([x[i:j]for i in r(len(x))for j in r(len(x))if{*map(chr,r(65,91))}<={*x[i:j].upper()}]or' ',key=lambda y:sum(map(str.isalpha,y)))
```

Having to sort based on the number of letters is killing me.

Test cases:

```
assert f("This isn't a pangram.") == ' '
assert f("Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).") == ' Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ig', f("Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).")
assert f('"The five boxing wizards jump quickly." stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" he shouted to the heavens.') == '. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', f('"The five boxing wizards jump quickly." stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" he shouted to the heavens.')
```

Comment: Don't think `.upper()` is needed in the key function.

Comment: @RootTwo Oops, yup, you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 180 bytes

This was hard, but really fun without imports.

```
l=['a'..'z']
u=['A'..'Z']
f&[]=[];f&x=x:f&f x
g#h=(.g).h.g
f x|v<-[y|y<-(tail&)=<<(init&x),and$zipWith((`elem`y)#(||))l u]=last$[]:[z|z<-v,all((length.filter(`elem`l++u))#(<=)$z)v]
```

Much less golfed:

```
lowerCase = ['a'..'z']
upperCase = ['A'..'Z']

f & x = takeWhile (not . null) $ iterate f x

(#) = flip on

subStrings x = (tail &) =<< (init & x)

pangram p = and $ zipWith ((`elem` p) # (||)) lowerCase upperCase

leqLetters x y = (length . filter (`elem` lowerCase ++ upperCase)) # (<=)

fewestLetters xs = [ x | x <- xs, all (leqLetters x) xs]

safeHead [] = ""
safeHead xs = head xs

f x = safeHead . fewestLetters . filter pangram . subStrings
```

Surprise, surprise: it's really slow.

Answer (score 2):

### Oracle SQL 11.2, 461 bytes

```sql
WITH s AS (SELECT SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)c,LEVEL p FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1)),v(s,f,l)AS(SELECT c,p,p FROM s UNION ALL SELECT s||c,f,p FROM v,s WHERE p=l+1),c AS(SELECT CHR(96+LEVEL)c FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<27),a AS(SELECT LISTAGG(c)WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1) a FROM c)SELECT MIN(s)KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH(s)-NVL(LENGTH(TRANSLATE(LOWER(s),' '||a,' ')),0))FROM(SELECT s,f,SUM(SIGN(INSTR(LOWER(s),c)))x FROM v,c GROUP BY s,f),a WHERE x=26;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
WITH s AS (SELECT SUBSTR(:1,LEVEL,1)c,LEVEL p FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=LENGTH(:1))
,v(s,f,l) AS
(
  SELECT c,p,p FROM s
  UNION ALL
  SELECT s||c,f,p FROM v,s WHERE p=l+1 
)
,c AS(SELECT CHR(96+LEVEL)c FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<27)
,a AS(SELECT LISTAGG(c)WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1) a FROM c)
SELECT MIN(s)KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH(s)-NVL(LENGTH(TRANSLATE(LOWER(s),' '||a,' ')),0))
FROM(SELECT s,f,SUM(SIGN(INSTR(LOWER(s),c)))x FROM v,c GROUP BY s,f),a
WHERE x=26
```

The `s` view splits the input in characters and also returns the position of each character.

The recursive view `v` returns every substring of the input
  s is the substring
  f the position of the first character of the substring
  l the position of the last character added to the current substring

The `c` view returns the alphabet, one letter at a time

The `a` view returns the alphabet concatenated as a single string

`SELECT s,f,SUM(SIGN(INSTR(LOWER(s),c))` 
  Returns for each substring the number of distinct letters present in it
  `INSTR` returns the pos of a letter in the substring, 0 if not present
  `SIGN` returns 1 if pos > 0, 0 if pos = 0

`WHERE x=26`
  Filters the substring containing the whole alphabet

`TRANSLATE(LOWER(s),' '||a,' ')`
  Deletes every letter from the substring

`LENGTH(s)-NVL(LENGTH(TRANSLATE(LOWER(s),' '||a,' ')`
  Length in letters is the length of the substring minus the length of the subtring without letters

`SELECT MIN(s)KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH(s)-NVL(LENGTH(TRANSLATE(LOWER(s),' '||a,' ')),0))`
  Keeps only the substring with the smaller letter count.
  If there is more than one, the first one, sorted as strings ascending, is kept

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell (v4), <s>198</s> 156 bytes

```powershell
param($s)
-join(@(1..($y=$s.Length)|%{$w=$_
0..$y|%{(,@($s[$_..($_+$w)]))}}|?{($_-match'[a-z]'|sort -U).Count-eq26}|sort -Pr {($_-match'[a-z]').count})[0])


# Previous 198 byte golf
$a,$b,$c=@(1..($s="$args").Length|%{$w=$_
0..($s.Length-$w)|%{if((($t=$s[$_..($_+$w)]-match'[a-z]')|sort -u).Count-eq26){(,@($t.Length,$_,$w))}}}|sort -pr{$_[0]})[0]
(-join($s[$b..($b+$c)]),'')[!$a]
```

#### Test Cases

```powershell
PS C:\> .\PangramWindow.ps1 "This isn't a pangram."


PS C:\> .\PangramWindow.ps1 'Everyone knows about that infamous Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ignoramus of a dog so many years ago).'
Quick-Brown-Fox (the one who jumped over some lazy ig

PS C:\> .\PangramWindow.ps1 '"The five boxing wizards jump quickly." stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. "ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!" he shouted to the heavens.'
ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!
```

---

#### Ungolfed explanation of the original

It's a brute-force nested loop which makes sliding windows of all sizes:

```powershell
.SubString(0, 1) -> slide window over the string
.SubString(0, 2) -> slide window over the string
..
.SubString(0, string.Length) -> slide window over the string
```

For each window, it filters for only letters (case insensitive regex matching by default), runs the remaining characters through a unique filter, checks if there are 26 unique characters as the pangram test.

All windows with pangrams are turned into triplets of *(number of letters including dupes, start index, window length including punctuation)*, which get sorted to find the shortest by overall character count, the first one is picked, and the output string built from that.

There's a lot of indexing outside the bounds of the string, which PowerShell usefully returns $null for, instead of throwing exceptions.

NB. the new 156 byte one is the same approach, but rewritten to use the pipeline a lot more.

```powershell
$string = "$args"

# increasing window widths, outer loop
$allPangramWindows =  foreach ($windowWidth in 1..$string.Length) {

    # sliding windows over string, inner loop
    0..($string.Length - $windowWidth) | ForEach {

        # slice window out of string, returns a char array
        $tmp = $string[$_..($_+$windowWidth)]

        # filter the char array to drop not-letters
        $tmp = $tmp -match '[a-z]'

        # Drop duplicate letters
        $tmpNoDupes = $tmp | sort -Unique

        # If we're left with a 26 character array, this is a pangrammatic window. Output
        # a PowerShell-style tuple of count of letters, start index, width.
        if($tmpNoDupes.Count -eq 26){
            (,@($tmp.Length,$_,$windowWidth))
        }
    }
}

# Force the result into an array (to handle no-results), sort it
# by the first element (num of letters in the window, total)
$allPangramWindows = @( $allPangramWindows | sort -Property {$_[0]} )

# take element 0, a window with the fewest letters
$windowCharCount, $windowStart, $WindowEnd = $allPangramWindows[0]

# uses the results to find the original string with punctuation and whitespace
if ($windowLen) {
    $string[$windowStart..($windowStart + $windowLen)] -join ''
}
```

NB. not sure the ungolfed version works, because I didn't write that then golf it, it's just for exposition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>111,110,108</s> 96 bytes

```
!S=minimum(['A':'Z'⊆(r=S[i:j])|>uppercase ? sum(isletter,r) : Inf,r]
for i=(k=keys(S)),j=k)[2]
```

### Attempt This Online!

- credits to @MarcMush: [96 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZC_TsMwEMbn5imuHhpbShmYUCWXPxJInSJUJqpKmMZJnNR25D-UQGcGXoGlSx-qG-JJcChQiZHpTnffd99P97at_FKwze49Y47RWYRuSmFBWBU7YNAwVRgmjxDQMSAUocsHblqtONRKryywe-0duJI5ECpnUnsL114s6uGF0Ss1vNKPgF3JobOsSg2Vlw3PQIczYLXksGRPLYhC6RATzDoPqZkuwhIkUy20nJmQU2jyDfGv8yiab73Lhye7u_6USqGE9BLP4vN4FN_GH68v2NDpTIyqOVmPfdNws2CWwynYIBN2yZ3jJjEERjBReWLmUa4NCIprWvPW4ikhSUVrMjv-yXnuBHiSpIR2n416aUqhP4l6Z8xabhzglFKEYDCA9KsjsF4DPhD9UuA0JZ1sob1yB5gwpfTvjJCIq2yPsNns6yc)
- my first attack: [108 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVJPb9MwFJe4NRe-wmuQ1lhqK7ET6uTCBh10wMKWMWBVD27ymrhLnoPttMvYmQNfgUsv-1Bw5JPgdNMkJg4IX2w9v9-f97O_Xy-qXIr1zwcPE2EFn3harHzfP8mkAWmoY0FAKSjVoui7OvAheC3f7972jZaoa0UI56RWBsRMVRZsJixImotCVQaOKhmf9_a0WlFvX11AYDOEBrLKFCyqosQElKMBowqEXFzWIFNSTtCB1dzpJyp1l1AIqqFGoZ1Oqlhjhw-dmf8SuJsA3KwIc7lEmKkLSSms5KXQidlA4XNDntd9H4wV1jEdqIyo7sIM50o7DKaSqIFZBRpjaREafZGXmZihdWw2czPMKoqzZhyDhYxVrsjlS5vWQiZJjn3wd_eevxjtv3w13vlzHbx-8_YwfHd0HJ28P_3w8dNZ2weHM5kL2zlywg1NhmKJZO5i-Wc2F8XUe1RqSTan4HR0HI3DQ3Zd2XnvyY-8HfFCkiyqIgg0jyZysJjudHY7g85Z59e3r1VZoo6FwUAzeAqxqsgG0uRoLequZnyoYQDbxIe-zzwXGUj-eBAQz5FSmwURY92FqxCbbE9vNb80bcG4GzLefEqvFYYc2mOv9UwYg9pCEHLuXm5rC8LNicHVFQR_MxWGrGm7Z8tVOb9fY8xDSm4srNc3-28)

It returns `""` for falsy cases; very ineffective (both for time and for memory); it does not optimize for window size/length - only the letter length is considered

Comment: [96 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nZC_TsMwEMbn5imuHhpbShmYUCWXPxJInSJUJqpKmMZJnNR25D-UQGcGXoGlSx-qG-JJcChQiZHpTnffd99P97at_FKwze49Y47RWYRuSmFBWBU7YNAwVRgmjxDQMSAUocsHblqtONRKryywe-0duJI5ECpnUnsL114s6uGF0Ss1vNKPgF3JobOsSg2Vlw3PQIczYLXksGRPLYhC6RATzDoPqZkuwhIkUy20nJmQU2jyDfGv8yiab73Lhye7u_6USqGE9BLP4vN4FN_GH68v2NDpTIyqOVmPfdNws2CWwynYIBN2yZ3jJjEERjBReWLmUa4NCIprWvPW4ikhSUVrMjv-yXnuBHiSpIR2n416aUqhP4l6Z8xabhzglFKEYDCA9KsjsF4DPhD9UuA0JZ1sob1yB5gwpfTvjJCIq2yPsNns6yc)

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 123 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
import Data.Char
h x=take 1$sortOn((1<$).filter isAlpha)[e|e<-powerslice x,['a'..'z']\\map toLower e==""]
```

Defines a function `h`, which returns the empty list if there's no pangrammatic window or a one element list with the minimum window.  Usage example:

```
*Main>  h "'The five boxing wizards jump quickly.' stated Johnny, before beginning to recite the alphabet with a bunch of semicolons in the middle. 'ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!' he shouted to the heavens."
[". 'ABCDEFGHI;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
```

How it works:

```
          [e|e<-powerslice x                  ]  -- for all continuous subsequences
                                                 -- e of the input  
                ,['a'..'z']\\map toLower e==""   -- keep those where the list
                                                 -- difference with all letters is
                                                 -- empty, i.e. every letter appears
                                                 -- at least once
    sortOn((1<$).filter isAlpha)                 -- sort all remaining lists on
                                                 -- their length after removing all
                                                 -- non-letters -> (1<$) see below
take 1                                           -- take the first, i.e. the minimum


calculating the length of a list: we're not interested in the length itself, but
in the relative order of the length. (1<$) replaces each element in a list with
the number 1, e.g. "abc" -> "111", "abcd" -> "1111", etc. Such '1'-strings have
the same order as the length of the original list. One byte saved!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ŒʒlêAå}éΣág}н
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY5LUsJAFEW38szYygYcgfjDD4jgh1l38pJ@2nkP0h0Uq9gEO7AsB7gHRyknDih3FDrOvON7zr3ilCZsmu/1z9rWn536Y1Vvtu/1W776/WqaaGwQMlogaHkhzuGZXlWZOnisihnMK0qe7DKOwHnlMYW@GOblPmjMpAwM5sTcYl6gxIQ8gg9CZWdGafTB5g0o0BUnBiQDhwUlYoUdEP9VC0pTizFEne5h7@j45PTs4H/65xeXV4Ph9ehmPLm9u3@Y7kUQOGekah@F4VZjUC2QXbwD) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VZA7TsNAEIb7nGJwE5CIDwBFFB6BhEd4hGe3jifeJfZM8K4THJFL5AYIUcABEA0NFg0F4kZhHCq2nJ3/@34NWxUYnN@PvBYNM7cG4NXzatUv3lYrXidzi5mM5p@zr1lcvDSKp2nx/P1YPETTn/f53@bHa33e1caCsVR1oGCoKEpV4le2R5jmTAgD4rEFFXDmwGnlwFBfJZxZOM5Mb1DbSHlMtSbfwbLTCGVkrBlusmSIIbBgwHKCEKtJDiYiFryEuS@2kCP5hERRDjmqVDwRr/gVryukvhkhBHxnKIKxmag0tAsq3JbeOPc9sE45kbRZE@WrEGCfU8lgZIjKmGNIsWccQllNxUOtAnRCc1rsQUY9XRaxmJgex0xyB1qsJiYMY/TBa2xsbm03d3Zb6/9fe2//4LBzdHxy2j07v7i8ul7yQHJWy5mkkYhLjEY1QrL@Lw).

Or alternatively with just a sort-by without filter:

```
ŒéΣláDêAQig]н
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY5NUsJAEIWv0mZt5QKuEPwBQQXxB6pYzCSdTOukGzMTFI/hDSxXcgdXKbYWNwoTd7z1@773xClN2DTbz/rn79vWX7160xlTvtj9Nk00NQgZrRC0vBPn8EYfqkwdPFfFEl4rSl7sOo7AeeUxhYEY5vUxaMykDAzmxNxiXqDEhDyCD0Jll0Zp9MHmDSjQFScGJAOHBSVihR0Q/1cLSlOLMUSd027v7Pzisn9ymMHVcHR9czue3E3vHx6fZvOjCALnjFTtozDcagyqFbKL9w) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VZBLTgJBEIb3nKLsDZrIHEAXBEV8iyjiI3HRwxTTLTNVON0DDPEU3sC40gMYN24kbo03whpc2cvq@r/vT7HTocXFw1jt0yj3GwCqXlSrwfx9vaLauV/OZKQWX4/zl@/nZP7UnL82Oja@/flYqKD3t/v5Vl90jXVgHVU9aBhpijOdBpWdMWYFE8KQeOJAh5x78EZ7sDTQKecOOrntD2tbGU@o1uIprHqDUEYmhuEuT0cYAQsGHKcIiZ4VYGNiwUuYB2KLOJZPSDUVUKDOxBPzWlBRXSEN7Bgh5KmlGCZ2prPILalwX3qTIlDgvPYiOWBDVKxDiAPOJIOxJSpjniHDvvUIZTWdjIwO0QvNG7GHOfVNWcRhavucMMkdaLma2ihKMADV2Npu7rR29/Y3/7@Dw6Pjk/Zp5@y8e9G7vLq@WVEgOWfkTNJIxCXGoB4jueAX).

Both output an empty string as falsey. (Could have been 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) if we would be allowed to output `-1` as falsey with `ŒéΣág}.ΔlêAå`.)

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ       # Get all substrings of the (implicit) input-string
 ʒ      # Filter this list by:
  l     #  Convert the current substring to lowercase
   ê    #  Uniquify and sort all characters in the string
    A   #  Push "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     å  #  Check if the lowercase alphabet is in the uniquify-sorted substring
 }é     # After the filter: sort any remaining substrings from shortest to longest
   Σ    # Then sort it again by:
    á   #  Leave just all the letters of the substring
     g  #  Pop and push the length for the amount of letters
   }н   # After the sort-by: pop and leave just the first
        # (or an empty string if the list is empty)
        # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
Œ           # Get all substrings of the (implicit) input-string
 é          # Sort them by length (shortest to longest)
  Σ         # Then sort it again by:
   l        #  Convert the current substring to lowercase
    á       #  Leave just all the letters of the substring
     D      #  Duplicate it
      ê     #  Uniquify and sort all characters in the letters in the string
       AQi  #  Pop, and if it's equal to the lowercase alphabet:
          g #   Pop and push the length for the amount of letters
  ]         # Close both the if-statement and sort-by
            # (note, integers are always sorted before strings, even if there are
            # digits in the input-string)
   н        # Pop and leave just the first result
            # (or an empty string if the list is empty)
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```