# Is it a valid list?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, parsing, balanced-string, ragged-list

Given a string like `[[[],[[]]],[]]`, made of only commas and square brackets, your challenge is to determine whether it represents a list.

A list is either:

- `[]`, the empty list
- At least one list, joined with commas and wrapped in square brackets.

You may use any three characters instead of `[,]`.

You may output as:

- Any two consistent values representing truthy and falsy
- One consistent value representing either truthy or falsy, and anything else as the other.

Output by erroring/not erroring *is* allowed, although `eval`-like solutions may be trickier than you think. Sometimes erroring and sometimes returning is *not*.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

#### Truthy

```
[[]]
[[],[]]
[[[[]],[[],[[]]],[]],[]]
[[[[]]]]
[]
```

#### Falsy

```
]
[[][]]
[,]
,
[],[]
[[[]][[]]]
[[],]
,[]
[[]
[,[]]
[][]
[[],
```

Comment: Do solutions need to handle the empty string as a (falsey) input?

Comment: Suggested test case: `,[]`

Comment: In "One consistent value representing either truthy or falsy, and anything else as the other," can the "anything else" include sometimes returning a value and sometimes erroring?

Comment: @DLosc Empty string - no, sometimes erroring, no.

Comment: Suggested test case: `[[]`

Comment: For counting consistency is it ok to ignore output to stdout like [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248696/56656) does?  The output to stderr is consistent / non-consistent, but the output to stdout is not consistent.

Comment: @WheatWizard As the defaults allow ignoring stderr, I think it's reasonable to also allow ignoring stdout. Many of the other JSON ones have a inconsistent return value. (so yes)

Comment: Suggested test case: `[,[]]`

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[][]` and `[[],` – without these, the .NET regex can be reduced to 25 bytes and pass all test cases

Comment: Let's mourn that Mathematica has `ListQ` ... which doesn't quite meet these specs for non-lists.

Answer (score 14):

## JavaScript, 10 bytes

```js
JSON.parse
```

Outputs via the presence or absence of an error.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY4/C4MwEMX3fIo4mUDqXJC4denQDh1twCAJtYiG5CoW8bOn8aTQtTfcn/fg9@6pJx1a3zk4TMdoZTzfrpfCaR9MBBNABlkthKYC/168gZcfaJZZFni5ot5qaB/M8K9pdR9M8lbS1LVSJDWxz@0UeKYFxR9DqaYIru@A5fch54Ud/Ukn8ExlRZ3vBmDbP2zmnJdkF9LSYABihCKCYBhBIlIx/h90/AA)

Answer (score 8):

## Python3, 70 bytes:

```
def f(s):
 try:return s==str(eval(s)).replace(' ','')
 except:return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9BasMwEEXX8SkGbySBCAnZlBhdIRdIvVCSMRUYWcxMSnN6V6PgRTbS4/8nxC8v@Vny6avQuj5wgsmyO3cg9DoTypMycAgsZPE3zrVze8IyxztaA8Yb4zrAvzsW2fTDyqHv@@56HcfhqJffSCPfggot/qgajsNB32hewevplVRtVW2a/PaaoN9NC0GClGFKsyDZy5LRA@@5zEms@c7G1V276OEGAdKWD3XALjIjSZ0eHYRaZrE31xVSMIIsDEWdh3HrPw)

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY9BasMwEEXX8SkGbySBCAnZlBhdIRdIvVCSMRUYWcxMSnN6V6PgRTbS4/8nxC8v@Vny6avQuj5wgsmyO3cg9DoTypMycAgsZPE3zrVze8IyxztaA8Yb4zrAvzsW2fTDyqHv@@56HcfhqJffSCPfggot/qgajsNB32hewevplVRtVW2a/PaaoN9NC0GClGFKsyDZy5LRA@@5zEms@c7G1V276OEGAdKWD3XALjIjSZ0eHYRaZrE31xVSMIIsDEWdh3HrPw), fixes the error signaled by @Unrelated String

Answer (score 8):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 0 bytes

Takes input from `stdin`, returns truthy iff `stderr` is empty.

PARI/GP automatically parses and evals everything from the `stdin`.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMGCpaUlaboWaNSy6OjY6NhYCA8A)

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function taking input as `[,]` with output by erroring/not erroring.

```apl
⎕JSON
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HfVK9gf7//aY/aJmg86u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qbCJQODnIGkiEensGa1QZWVgaPulsMH3UtftS7C4y21v5PU4@Ojo1V5wLTOnAmSFAHLAJkgMVR5aBsMAnTDVOgA6Z0IAp0omG6YmPBGmFWQRTBZGPVAQ) (wrapped in error trapping code to give 0 when erroring and 1 when not erroring)

Attempts to convert from JSON.

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 26 bytes

```haskell
f=opn*>isP f ʃ_*>cls
```

```
x1 f
```

Uses the characters `()_`.

Creates a parser object and uses `x1` to determine if some input matches the parser.

## 25 bytes

```
f('(':')':>x)=mF f$' '|\x
```

Uses the characters `()` .

Returns `True` on valid inputs and errors on invalid ones.

This version is 1 byte shorter but I'm not sure if it's allowed by the rules.  If you call the function expecting a bool, e.g.

```
f x::Bool
```

It will work. However by default ghci infers `()` as the type, which does not meet the output specifications of the challenge.  So you need to call it either with a type signature or in a context in which ghc can infer it's type to be `Bool`.

## Relfections

- hgl has a `unwords` function.  It could be made a pattern like in the curry answer:

  ```
  f('(':')':>Uw x)=mF f x
  ```
- It's rather annoying that `wR`, the `words` function trims leading spaces.  There is a 23 byte answer which would work if `wR` didn't do this.

  ```
  f('(':')':>x)=mF f$wR x
  ```
- `mF` should have an infix.
- `isP` should have an infix.
- `isP` should have a flip.

Answer (score 6):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>22</s> 23 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Ç╥╫ÜΦªt┌¢♣☺¢+╬ï▼6◘-6¡Zq
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=80d2d79ae8a674da9b05019b2bce8b1f36082d36ad5a71&i=%5B%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5D,%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B%5B%5D%5D,%5B%5B%5D,%5B%5B%5D%5D%5D,%5B%5D%5D,%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B%5B%5D%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5D%0A%5B%5B%5D%5B%5D%5D%0A%5B,%5D%0A,%0A%5B%5D,%5B%5D%0A%5B%5B%5B%5D%5D%5B%5B%5D%5D%5D%0A%5B%5B%5D,%5D%0A,%5B%5D%0A%5B,%5B%5D%5D&a=1&m=2)

#### Approach

- Repeatedly

  - Replace `"[[]]"` with `"[]"`
  - <s>Replace `",[]]"` with `"]"`</s>
  - Replace `"[[],["` with `"[["`
- Is result equal to `"[]"`?

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 19 bytes (@dingledooper)

```
eval("set"+input())
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU07DsIwDN1zimAJKVbEgFhQmVlhYEJMVeVCJJRGwUXtWVi6wAU4TW5D6nZgsd_Xfn1Cz7fGD2lRN1E77byOpb-SWW-wUJpjX1BHlQGAd8v1avulZ3k38CAG63xo2SBOTlrmEO5CdJ4NnPcnQKWpqyhwMYuHI8zhIV1Mbqo87LRHaoVmIOKfMQJUEhfRorJKqkp8ycixbJj5xw8)

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 22 bytes

```
def f(s):eval("set"+s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZAxDsIwDEXFmlNYXkhoYEa5SslQtYmoqNIoCag9C0sXOAKH4TQkqSoVMbHY_v6y_eT7047h3JtpelyD3h9fjdKgqWdC3aqOolcBC89m873Z6t4BDNAaQMSylJLEwOecJM8yFrm5MlIh48zB264NFE8GmSg1HQ5O2a6qFd2hZMhWsqRfkhfImKxMA9a1Jq7oL8gISUQLUKbJN7kknGQyks9nhMwajV8QAgDBjeJvnjSohlrZINZU87-Wp34A)

This takes a string composed of the characters "(+)" and signals by erroring/not erroring.

##### How?

Why can't we just use `eval`?

1. trailing commas
2. missing outer brackets

Both will be tolerated by `eval`.

To address 1 we replace `,` with `+`.

To address 2 we switch from `[]` to  `()` and prepend `set`.

#### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 28 bytes

```
def f(s):eval(s+","+s[1:-1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBDoMgEEX3nGIyK6ho4q7hKpSFUUhNDRKkjZ6lGzftKXqRXqMnKGJMTNoNzJ_5M2_g_nRTOPd2nh_XYPLjq9EGDB2Y0Leqo0OGHLNBliIvFVst74_pPcAIrQVElFIpEg--3ovkScYgJXeFJVCxpxhc1waKJ4tMSEPHwmvXVbWmB-QZMqYq24DzrY2m_oKMkIW5IRMvTeWKcJLYJAESJG0TC78oAgDBT2Kd_IfLFocea-2C2OPXl2-f9AU)

This takes a string composed of the characters "[+]" (note that we have cheekily but legally replaced "," with "+") and signals by erroring/not erroring.

I'm not 100% sure this is correct but it works on all test cases.

Comment: Nice. Alternative: `def f(s):eval('zip'+s)` and using `(,)`

Comment: @mathjunkie I believe that will miss trailing commas like `s="((),)"`.

Comment: I suppose taking input via STDIN will save a few bytes: `eval("set"+input())`

Answer (score 5):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 29 bytes

```
f('[':unwords a++"]")=all f a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NQz1a3ao0rzy/KKVYIVFbWylWSdM2MSdHIU0h8X9uYmaegi2QqRQNBLGxCkAChEEsCFb6DwA)

Uses a space   instead of `,`. Returns `True` for truth, and nothing otherwise.

---

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 53 bytes

```
f('[':a++"]")=g a
f"[]"=1
g(a++',':b)=f a*g b
g a=f a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NQz1a3SpRW1spVknTNl0hkStNKTpWydaQK10DKKquo26VpGmbppCola6QxAWUB7H/5yZm5inYKqQpKEUDQWysDpAAYRALgpX@AwA)

Returns `1` for truth, and nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Whython](https://github.com/pxeger/whython), 36 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval(s)>=[]!=",]"not in s?0
```

Returns `True` for valid lists, `False` or `0` for invalid lists. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZBNCsIwEIX3OcUYXDQQwaUUogepWVSb0kJNJBl_ehY3BRHP5Gm0SdsUXM1778v8kMf7VrVYGd09S7F_XbBcbT7LJj8dihxcqq55kzi2FZlcCMol1Qah1uB26_HtF5VDBwIyAjSTlPuSySj4rH3MQ9SLAP7gaGJvpHyofJov-eAnF_f2HWFQ3O6VJKWx4O_0p4d7UwJnW2tMvOOgdCEoUEYAbduzEZYBsz5W96M640xooqw1llE2fEPXDfUH)

#### Explanation

```python
lambda s:eval(s)>=[]!=",]"not in s?0
lambda s:                             # Anonymous function that takes s, a string
         eval(s)                      # Python eval
                >=[]                  # True if the result is a list, error if tuple
                    !=                # Keep the comparison chain going
                      ",]"not in s    # Check that there are no extra commas
                                  ?0  # If anything raised an error, return 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(<(((?1),)*(?1))?>)$
```

Uses the characters `<>,`. (Avoids `[]` as they would require being `\`-escaped.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/a8MwEMV3fYojFpFUVBwPXSxZJpB27JSxVDhBAYPqpJIzFON@dfek0JIu9@e93727uOCflo8voEHB5M/HzgMtFa6N3m33WzOT0zlw2jcbpY3CXokJ@hMqYrqEfhhh9Tas1AzUQwPxeogj4lY@VrIS7jOZ0N7pG3QE1ECtIoBBwPFwvf4jPBKVGBwr2O8DnpDmG0oayl60bB@urgZgNXvpfMSRCTVj2I2mXsFs7fPrztrlnWvOeVsJKR5SE60RdFkKSBkwujjCsYsuEqK1ManIW0@rzCsOWbwz0mAIKSD//xeTMzIpDZEk55F8lA/zBzSymCAUfwA) - Perl
[Try it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/M0oflp/1) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFRb5swEMff@RRXBxW7cpMQdZsSB3jY6BSpSipa7WXpLIpMQQOCbKd7mPrZs7P70LUP2Of//e93ZzM242mdjc0IoYYEyIzAFEatnqRWY1dWikaz6UUmZVN2VlaHfmw7pfd0z8S@mJmIQ4RfjaJ8Us4wWDVYQ6W83tzkUjIOMUMkmR1bIoL6j26tonf33/Ki4OT2a5Ev4Jkw8T6BGGPLwdLIOeSPvLjb7LYR@@gj@wFrg3ZopVGWkrHSavpYVr@txkV2bd9awoFcLZZXy89fFstPzl4fNA3bZC7CLqlxauNwmy0T7C@0NQ27n8bqTg0Yscv4IUl8GzSb4yNmUOZzfhkz4d0tU1VzcBYBSI1FAKgDfWOcnyNy/nCWRJMIW4R94h@4L23V0FBztAhwkNeH70pjpdIap2RnyW2Rf5fbncTr7oqM5E5fAVnRsM/IvT6qFeCJXJedwRCvBy84gKeRsCPi5cOvo0ycftE1pTSLGWcXbmNZysLTaQKOB1YZC1VplAmC9TpN3cJfd3fk/oiBF/9LuCANggn4Wd5hPMM7eRrwwPMCX@QLfQdMeNGZUPwH) - PCRE2 v10.33
[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVFLbtswEEW3PMWEFiIyoOMP0o9Ny1qkSmGgsAMl6KZOCUWgYqGyLJB0uyhyhJ6gmwBFj9DDtOhhOqQLtOlCnDdvHt8MR1--dpvu4eeTX7MUAUQGEqADCqfQGX2njO6aotQsHpyepEptisapcrft6kabNVtzuc4HNhYQ41chqe60F7ROt84ypS4WrzOluIARR0s62NdUkuqjqZ1mV9cvszwX9PI8z8bwgXL5uIA21hWtY7FXqDdZfrVYLWPOJanbWlntGO1Ko09vi_K9M3iopt7WjgqgZ-PJ2eTZ8_HkKdqSamdYVCdDGTVJhRNa32Kx5JJ_grpiUfPWOtPoFhHvj26ShK5bylFs97dYQVoMRX_EZVDXXJebnZdIQNeRJIA8sL8ex8doObw5SuJejC2ibRKWuS1cuWGRESiR4E0OS24K65Q2BqfkR8llnr1Sy5XCFazylGaenwKdsmib0muz11PAjF4UjUWIz4N7HCC40aih8v6_38S4_LZ3Vf_F93dsxhhLR1zwEx94OufRofbwJ_z43APfA5y2DsrCakvIbDaf-0Mcok9FSBEE8p-CB3NCehDme2QTPIJSzIkgwY-ES-Fi6ICFQHoRkoepfgM) - PCRE2 v10.39+

Like the regex in the Raku answer, this uses recursion. Unlike Raku, standard regex has no concept of "separator" characters, so there's no concise way of implementing a comma-separated list, and the recursive call `(?1)` needs to be in two places.

There are many alternatives of the same length:

#### Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(<((?1)(,(?2))?)?>)$
```

Also uses the characters `<>,`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NasMwEITveoolFpEEKo4LvVi2RCDtsaccS4UTFDCoTio5h2LcV3dXCi3pZX9mvp29uOCflo8voEHB5M/HzgMtFa5ts9vut3omp3PgtG83qtEKeyUm6E@oiOkS@mGE1duwUjNQDy3E6yGOiFv5UMlKuM9kgrnTN@gIqIFaRQCDgOPhev1HeCQqMThWsN8HPCHtN5Q0lL0wbB@urgZgNXvpfMSRCTVj2I2mXsFs7fPrztrlnTecm0pwyc2jEEYYLeiyFJAyYHRxhGMXXSSkabRORd56WmVeccjinZEGTUgB@f@/mJyRSamJJDmP5KN8mD@gkcUEofgD) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHBbtswDIbvfgpWMWppUJM46DYkiu3D5g4BhqRwi12WTnANuRbmOIakbIehz55R6mFrD5apnz8/UtLYjed1MXYjxAYyIDMCUxiNepJGjX3dKJrMpu8KKbu6d7I5HkbdK7Oneyb21cwmHBL8WhTlk/KGwanBWSrlzeZrKSXjkDJEktlJExG1v412it7dfy6ripPbT1W5gF@EidcJxFhXD44m3iG/ldXdZrdN2Fsf2Q9YG@lBS6scJWNj1PSxbn46g4vs9UE7woFcL5bXyw8fF8v33t4eDY11Nhdxn7U4tfW4zZYJ9gd0S@P@u3WmVwNG7Cp9yLLQBs329IgZlPmcX6VMBLdmqumO3iIAqamIAHWg/xiXl4icP1xkySTBFvEhCxd8qF3T0dhwtAjwkJeL72vrpDIGp2QX2W1VfpHbncTj7qqClF5fAVnR@FCQe3NSK8Adual7iyEeD55xgEAjcU/E85uno0ycf9A1pUXKKKfFgrGCFTmLz@cJeB44ZR00tVU2itbrPPcLf/n7LQ9bDIL4X8IHeRRNIMzyChMYwcnziEeBF4WiUBg6YCKI3oTiXw) - PCRE

Uses `(?2)` recursion instead of `*` repetition for the comma-separated list.

#### Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(a((?1),)*(?1)?\Bz)$
```

Uses the characters `az,` in order to take advantage of the `\B` non-word-boundary assertion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/b8IwEMV3f4oTsbCNXIUMLDEhoqIdOzGiWi4yUiQ3gB2GJkq/eno2akWX@/Pe795drHer6fMLqFcwuPPROKC5wrVa77b77WYkp7PntKmWar1R2AsxQHNCRQwX37QdzA7tTI1AHVQQbh@hQ1zLp0IWwl6jCfWDvkRHQAlUKwIYBBwP5/M/wiFRiNayjP0@4BGpviGnPm9Ezfb@ZksAVrJX4wKOTKgRw@40dQpGrV/edlpP79xwXhdCikVs9eG5F3SaMogZ0NnQwdEEGwgxpu9jkfceV5lWHJL4YMShJySD9P9fTMpIpOyJJCmPpKN0mD6gkcQIofgD) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFva9swEMbf@1NcFVNLRc0/uo1EM4Zt7giMpLhlb5ZOqEZuxGzHSEoHGf3s2Ul9sbUvLJ2ee@53J3nYDaePxbAbILWQA5kQGMNg9aO0emhVrWk2GV8UUu5U62W97wbTarulWya21cRlHDL8GhTlow6G3uveOyrl9epbKSXjMGOIJJODISJpflvjNb29@1JWFSc3n6tyDk@EidcJxDivek@z4JDfy@p2tVln7K2PbHusTUxvpNOekqG2evyg6l/e4iJb0xlPOJCr@eJq8f7DfPEu2Ju9panJpyJt8wandgG3WjPB/oBpaNr@cN62useIXc7u8zy2QbM7PGAGZT7llzMmotswXe/2wSIAqTORAOpA/zHOzxE5vT/Ls1GGLdIujw/cKV/vaGo5WgQEyMvDt8p5qa3FKdlZflOVX@V6I/G6m6ogZdCXQJY07QpyZw96CXgi16p1GOL14BkHiDSStkQ8v/l1lInTT6ooLWaMs4uwFdtPR5aeTiMIPPDaeaiV0y5JlDoew8Jf9nDk8YhBFP9LhOCYJCOIs7zCREZ08mPCk8hLYlEsjB0wEcVgQvEv) - PCRE

Without the use of `\B`, there would be nothing stopping a comma-separated list ending in a comma from being accepted, as the `(?1)?` is optional independently of whether or not `((?1),)*` matched anything.

The `\B` prevents this; if any list ended with a comma, the sequence `,z` would be part of it, so all we need to do is prohibit this sequence. `\Bz` accomplishes this, as `a` and `z` are word-characters but `,` is not, thus there is no word boundary in the middle of `az` or `zz` but there is one in `,z`.

#### Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(a\B(?1)?(,(?1))*z)$
```

Also uses the characters `az,`. Mirror version of the above.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/b8IwEMV3f4oTsbCNXIUMLDEhoqIdOzGiWi4yUiQ3gB2GJkq/eno2akWX@/Pe795drHer6fMLqFcwuPPROKC5wrVa77b77WYkp7PntKmWar1R2AsxQHNCRQwX37QdzA7tTI1AHVQQbh@hQ1zLp0IWwl6jCfWDvkRHQAlUKwIYBBwP5/M/wiFRiNayjP0@4BGpviGnPm9Ezfb@ZksAVrJX4wKOTKgRw@40dQpGrV/edlpP79wcnnldiJrL2MSiF3SaMogZ0NnQwdEEGwgxpu9jkfceV5lWHJL4YMShJySD9P9fTMpIpOyJJCmPpKN0mD6gkcQIofgD) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFva9swEMbf@1NcFVNLRc0/uo1EM4Zt7giMpLhlb5ZOqEZuxGzHSEoHGf3s2Ul9sbUvLJ2ee@53J3nYDaePxbAbILWQA5kQGMNg9aO0emhVrWk2GV8UUu5U62W97wbTarulWya21cRlHDL8GhTlow6G3uveOyrl9epbKSXjMGOIJJODISJpflvjNb29@1JWFSc3n6tyDk@EidcJxDivek@z4JDfy@p2tVln7K2PbHusTUxvpNOekqG2evyg6l/e4iJb0xlPOJCr@eJq8f7DfPEu2Ju9panJpyJt8wandgG3WjPB/oBpaNr@cN62useIXc7u8zy2QbM7PGAGZT7llzMmotswXe/2wSIAqTORAOpA/zHOzxE5vT/Ls1GGLdIujw/cKV/vaGo5WgQEyMvDt8p5qa3FKdlZflOVX@V6I/G6m6ogZdCXQJY07QpyZw96CXgi16p1GOL14BkHiDSStkQ8v/l1lInTT6q2n2gxYwXlYWMXR5aeTiMIPPDaeaiV0y5JlDoew8Jf9nDk8YhBFP9LhOCYJCOIs7zCREZ08mPCk8hLYlEsjB0wEcVgQvEv) - PCRE

#### Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(<(\B(?1)|\b,\B)*z)$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/b8IwEMV3f4oTsbBduQoZusQJEYh27MQY1QrISJHcQO0wNGn61dOzUSu63J/3fvfuYpx9mt8/gToFoz0fGws0VbiWxW6z36wncjo7TttypYq1wp6JEdoTKmK8uLbrYVF3CzUBtVCCvx58j7iWj5nMhPkIJlR3@godATlQrQhgEHA8XC7/CItEJjrDEvb7gAek/IaUurQVFdu7q8kBWM5eGutxZEJNGHajqVUwaf38utN6fuMFr7e8ysRXfZD1VjwMgs5zAiEDeuN7ODbeeEKKYhhCkbceVhlXHKJ4Z4RhICSB@P9fTMyIpByIJDGPxKN4GD@gEcUAofgD) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFva9swEMbf@1NcFVNLRc0/uo1EMYZu7giUpLhlb@ZOOEZpxGzHSMoGWfvZs5P6YmtfWD4999zvTlK/60@LrN/1EBtIgYwIDKE36kka1TdVrWgyGl5kUu6qxsl63/a6UaakJRNlMbIJhwS/LYrySXlD51TnLJXyZnmbS8k4TBgiyeigiYi2v412it4/fMmLgpO7z0U@hV@EibcJxFhXdY4m3iG/5cX9cr1K2HsfKTusjXSnpVWOkr42arip6p/O4CIb3WpHOJCr6exq9vHTdPbB27d7Q2OdjkXcpFuc2nrccsUE@wN6S@Pmu3WmUR1G7HLymKahDZrtYYMZlPmYX06YCG7NVL3be4sApE5EBKgD/cc4P0fk@PEsTQYJtojbNFxwW7l6R2PD0SLAQ14vvqmsk8oYnJKdpXdF/lWu1hKPuy4yknt9DmRO4zYjD@ag5oA7clM1FkM8HrzgAIFG4oaIl3dPR5k4/aALWl7TbMKeyw0vr9nFkcWn0wA8D5yyDurKKhtFi8Xx6Bf@@vdbHrYYBPG/hA@OUTSAMMsbTGAEJz9GPAq8KBSFwtABE0H0JhT/Ag) - PCRE

Uses the characters `<z,` in order to take advantage of the `\b` and `\B` word- and non-word-boundary assertions.

#### Regex (Perl / PCRE), 21 bytes

```
^(a((?1)\B|\B,\b)*>)$
```

Uses the characters `a>,`. Mirror version of the above.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0/b8IwEMV3f4oTsbBduQoZusTEEYh27MQY1QrISJHcQO0wVGn61dOzUSu63J/3fvfuYr17mt8/gXoFozsfWwc0V7hW691mv9ETOZ09p121UmutsBdihO6EihgvvusHWDT9Qk1AHVQQrocwIG7kYyELYT@iCfWdvkJHQAnUKAIYBBwPl8s/wiFRiN6yjP0@4BGpviGnPu9Ezfb@aksAVrKX1gUcmVATht1o6hRMxjy/7oyZ33jLeV2IZvvVbGVzEA9a0HnOIGbAYMMAxzbYQEjbah2LvPW4yrTikMQ7Iw6akAzS/38xKSORUhNJUh5JR@kwfUAjiRFC8Qc) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZFRb9MwEMff8ylubrTYk9c21QC1Jq00lqFKqJ2yiRcyLDdylog0jWwXHmCfvZy9B9ge4pz/97/fne2hGU4fV0MzQGwgAzIhMIbB6Cdp9NCpStNkMr5YSdmozsnqsB/aTpuSlkyUxcQmHBL8ahTlk/aG3uneWSrl7fpLLiXjkDJEksmxJSKqf5nWaXr/cJMXBSd3n4p8Bj8JE68TiLFO9Y4m3iG/5sX9ertJ2FsfKXusjdq@lVY7SobK6PFOVT@cwUV27b51hAO5ms2v5u8/zObvvL0@GBq32VTEXVbj1Nbj1hsm2G9oaxp336wzne4xYpfpY5aFNmi2xx1mUOZTfpkyEdwt01Vz8BYBSE1FBKgD/cc4P0fk9PEsS0YJtoj3WbjgvXJVQ2PD0SLAQ14uvlPWSW0MTsnOsrsi/yw3W4nH3RYrknt9AWRB4/2KPJijXgDuyK3qLIZ4PHjGAQKNxB0Rz2@ejjJx@k4VpauUldd/ymte7tjFksWn0wg8D5y2DipltY0ipZZLv/CXv9/ysMUgiP8lfLCMohGEWV5hAiM4@TLiUeBFoSgUhg6YCKI3ofgX) - PCRE

## Regex (.NET), <s>35</s> <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
^((a)+(?<-2>z)+(?(2),\b|$))+$
```

Uses the characters `az,` in order to take advantage of the `\b` word-boundary assertion.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BT8MwDIXv@RVWGqmJlqKxY8dgEhI3btzGkLLi0UihLWmnooz99pJ4QoMDl/jZfu9zunZE39fo3CT8auPxDT@3ZdngKNf59CKlUTN5d1MsbkMScqH08@5LKDUTU77W/L5976zDV66WIqzmy33r0VS1FA5sA8I23WFQRwZg91IEdRy9HbCo2344Rf81LSC6C/wAzqFoPQi3mW@pz7iClD0Buh5JAlwIUDRt/KizDQIXkkD@6tEMVY19ZKqYzp/8AUuA/IeRP5hYyzhQPKHZf0Th2GnKIOVhwLirTI89Y8aEkB59rqnV1EZBw1@LJAJjGdDRPxhikFMHphnxGIUoSBfigobJRNZwbvVFfQM)

Based on the old [**35 byte** one-liner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/248700/2) in [Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248700/17216).

*-1 byte by using the characters `<>,` instead of `[],`, because `[` needed to be `\`-escaped*
*-1 byte by using an illegal character, instead of `$.`, as the impossible condition to assert Group 2 being empty at the end*
*-4 bytes by using the characters `az,` instead of `<>,`, obviating the need for explicitly asserting Group 2 is empty at the end*

```
^                # Assert that we're at the beginning of the string.
(
    (a)+         # Capture at least one "a" on the Group 2 stack.
    (?<-2>z)+    # Match at least one "z", popping an entry from the Group 2
                 # stack for each one we match.
    (?(2),\b|$)  # If the Group 2 stack is non-empty, match a "," followed by a
                 # word boundary (since "," is a non-word character, this means
                 # it must be followed by a word character, i.e. [0-9A-Za-z_]),
                 # else assert that we're at the end of the string.
)+               # Loop the above at least 1 time.
$                # Assert that we're at the end of the string. The Group 2
                 # conditional at the end of the above loop guarantees that the
                 # only way to end the loop at the end of the string is for
                 # Group 2 to be empty, due to the "\b" in its non-empty
                 # clause. So there's no need to explicitly assert here
                 # something like "(?(2)$.)" (which would assert something
                 # impossible in the case that Group 2 is non-empty).
```

Note that if the `<>,` characters are still used, it can be **32 bytes**:

```
^((<)+(?<-2>>)+(?(2),(?!$)|$))+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BT8MwDIXv@RUmjdRES9HYseuySUjcuHGbhlQVj0YKbUk7FW3st5fEExo7cImf7fc@p2tH9H2Nzk3Cr7Ye3/Frl@cNjnKTTq9SFmom10W2MCYKuVBaru@E@hZKzcSUbjR/bD866/CNq6U4rubLfeuxrGopHNgGhG26w6BODMDupTiq0@jtgFnd9sM5@B9oAcGd4SdwDlnrQbjtfEd9whXE7BnQ9UgS4EqArGnDX51tELiQBPL3z@VQ1dgHpgrp9MUfMAdIfxnpUxlqHgaKRzT7jygcO08JxDwMGHZV2WPPWFEYEx99qbHV1AZBwz@LKAxjCdDRGwwxyKkN04x4jEIUpAthQcNoIqu5tPqqfgA)

#### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/), 33 bytes

```
sub{pop=~/^(<(((?1),)*(?1))?>)$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU49b4MwEN39K05gBbtylDB0wWCWqEOHdmjHqhGNTIoEhNpGVYToX6dnI1Xp4nv3vs6DNu39MloN1pnm5CR4/F2ZvunPdt0eX56fVnSoXJVlh7EbtJHQXYHWxWLHj2m4DMXP7p3ljLEy5YLf@cFLxeluXmR9May70qbYy1xJnCmfoKkZbfg0mKZ3EL31kZxDZQsFYCf@h9Gj2KYi5frL61De8HtUOGRAj5IAdgFrdX92nxjfbP58LfpS3uskTvhEj0UUyfUeo/VWoc7L5NWMOgNIsuShai3ChMsZO1cjbSXMSwzeBU5bB6fKaktInivlH7FOv4qwIgjkjeCBIiSGcOFfTegITqGIIKGPhFAIhgsoBNKbkPwF)

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>44</s> 39 bytes

```
\(L)grepl('^(<(((?1),)*(?1))?>)$',L,,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY49TsQwEIV7n2LYoPUMMhLp0OZnO6qUSDQrpJC1F0uRN_IkTRBH4AQ0CxJX4C57G2yHAhqP58333sz7hz99muprGs317VnusKGD10OP8hFLRNzmpOgqFtrWdClVo1ROv_g3VzcFzJWxvcYVj3vrVlQIc_TYgHXA0zB4zfzQemfdgdHrdt9YpxlnInoRANYgU9eOKHdOUsFVXiyq657bEEOwXoecJx5Do_Kw-6KSmSSIHmt0zxpNwJS895PeAEgl79qgbkASxawINlS8iq4_BnimYrn-dH7LIJpg1DwGjDULUZZ1HR-11Niq1IZPEv8M4qcWIoO08F9MykikqoUSKU8kUzKmDWGQxAgFcbnqBw)

*-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe*
*-4 bytes by using `grepl()` instead of `sum(grep())` or `any(grep())`*
*-5 bytes by using a new anonymous function syntax introduced in R v4.1.0*

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>46</s> 42 bytes

```
$args-match'^((a)+(?<-2>z)+(?(2),\b|$))+$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU3LTsMwELz7K1bJitiqLZUeWwo3voAbD8lUmyaSSYqdKpJDvj3YW6HCgcvuzM5jT/1IPjTk3IL1flrQ@mMwH3Y4NNWblFat5MOd2dzHDORG6Zf3L1RqhdUy7zDu17u692QPjUQHbQfYdqfzoCYB0NYSo5pG3w5kmj4Mc/LfsgDJbegTigJM7wHd8/qVeVkoyNkZyAViCHBtANP1HY2u7QgKlLnoBuuUT6nqyZ9pC1D9ZKtHm/Y2HVSRK8V/TejEvJSQ8zBQ0g42UBDC2hjz0JedqWaaAB9/CRlEIUrgp39quIOdOgotuE9wiIP8IQl8zCa2xgvVV/QN)

Comment: You can omit the `0` in the R answer, so it's `grep(...,,1)`

Answer (score 4):

## [Yacc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc), 22 bytes

```
s:'['b']'b:l|l:s|s','l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwFEX3fMUDCWmlxr2Wbrr6ASVDkoY2EBrIexWD9dtjFYcDl3OHYzTOxWqCrhPX@01AHzySzIwj6USAjPOCrRiEEUqYNmyhxQ1FI0LhnB38YsM6OuiQRh/l3LNH9CPk7FKKqbKzTnCsL8wvtMvgnlX9So7WtMDk6HtX9eXN9jTL2lr416d9ZknaSAunkJk8axlXKsOgmh9KfQA) (note: Yacc is installed on TIO, but doesn't have a TIO wrapper, so I had to write one myself; I also wrapped the function into a full program. The wrapper outputs by exit code.)

Function submission. (I originally forgot PPCG allowed functions to be sumbitted, so the first version of this was a full program with a lot of boilerplate. Submitting it as a function obviously makes more sense.)

This is a function/parser named `s` that reads input from `yacc`'s usual input source. It does the `yacc` equivalent of throwing an exception if the input is not a list, or returns normally if the input is a list. (It doesn't explicitly return a value – Yacc uses "implicit int" like in C, so these parsers are technically returning integers, but we don't set the return value to anything in particular.)

This function uses `[`, `]`, `,` as suggested by the question, but could easily be adapted to use any three characters (although some choices would make the program longer due to needing to be escaped).

### Explanation

Yacc is a language for writing parsers; you provide a description of syntactically legal input and it generates a parser for you. This program contains three parsers, `s`, `b` and `l`:

```
s:'['b']'b:l|l:s|s','l
s:                       An "s" is
  '['                      an opening square bracket
     b                     then a "b"
      ']'                  then a closing square bracket;
         b:              A "b" is
           l|              either an "l", or {an empty string};
             l:          An "l" is
                |          either
               s             an "s"
                |          or 
                 s           an "s"
                  ','        followed by a comma
                     l       followed by another "l"
```

A direct translation of the question to Yacc would be `s:'['']'|'['l']'l:s|s','l`, but factoring out the brackets from the two branches of `s` into a separate rule `b` allows the program to be a byte shorter.

Yacc programs don't normally look this condensed; they're normally written with more whitespace, and semicolons between rules. However, the semicolons are optional, and whitespace is optional except between two identifiers (and I arranged this program so that it never had two identifiers in a row, allowing all the whitespace to be golfed off). A weird side effect of this flexibility is that Yacc's syntax is very hard to parse due to false positives (e.g. `b:l|l` is a valid rule, but `b:l|l:` has to be parsed as `b:l|; l:` despite that), and in fact, it isn't sufficiently powerful to write a parser for its own syntax (it's powerful, but its syntax is weird enough that it needs even more power to parse). It's helpful in golfing, though!

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>39</s> <s>35</s> 23 bytes

```
<<>>
<>
}`<<>,<
<<
^<>$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYw7DoBACET7OYcmW3CECaewI5i1sLCxMLaeHVlsbODNB679Ps4t5taWbt6pQaqCiqcnCUFipU4RZu7IId8eUkomlPkLBjiqXqY4BHWKyqtTzzIwfwE) Takes `<,>` characters but link is to test suite that converts from `[]` for convenience. Explanation: Port of @recursive's Stax solution.

```
<<>>
<>
```

Remove an empty list that's the only element of a list.

```
<<>,<
<<
```

Remove an empty list that's the first element of a list.

```
}`
```

Repeat until there are no more elements to remove.

```
^<>$
```

Check that we finished with an empty list.

Escaping means that it takes 29 bytes to use `[,]` characters:

```
\[\[]]
[]
}`\[\[],\[
[[
^\[]$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYwhEoBADAN93gEzJ/oPHpGWOQQCg2CwvL2UnEE1yaa59vs4t5xbW3o6nRFg4OnS5gSJteSUScFKx/2syZZQ@ANjRnWFFjDoFeLqaKwA4wU) Link includes test cases.

Previous 35-byte one-liner:

```
^((\[)+(?<-2>])+(?(2),|$))+(?(2)$.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wP05DIyZaU1vD3kbXyC4WxNAw0tSpUdGEMlX0NP//j46OjeUCEjoQGsTVAXOBDLAgkgSIEcsFVg4W1Inl0uECa@UCy4PVgA0DSkTHAgA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
^(
```

Start matching at the beginning of the string.

```
(\[)+
```

Count the number of `[`s.

```
(?<-2>])+
```

Count some `]`s, but no more than the number of `[`s so far.

```
(?(2),|$)
```

After each run of `[`s and `]`s, if there are still unbalanced `]`s, then there must be a `,` next, otherwise we must be at the end of the string.

```
)+
```

Repeat as many times as necessary.

```
(?(2)$.)
```

Check that there weren't more `[`s than `]`s.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by changing `(?(2)$.)` to e.g. `(?(2)z)`, since the statement of the question guarantees that the input is made of only commas and square brackets. You can save another 1 byte by using e.g. `<,>`, as the question also state you may use any three characters instead of `[,]`.

Comment: @Deadcode On the other hand I could just not do it as a 1-liner...

Comment: Nice, that's more in line with what I'd expect from Retina.  Is it okay with you if I adapt your old answer as a .NET regex sub-answer in my answer?

Comment: @Deadcode If you mean the 2 byte savings you mentioned above then sure. If you mean something else that I can backport while maintaining compatibility then I might want to update my answer with the appropriate saving.

Comment: Thanks, done. It's just the 2 bytes; I had to suggest two new test cases because without them, the regex could be reduced to 25 bytes and pass all test cases.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `P`, 8 bytes

```
øBEÞfSȧ=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhUOG5oCIsIsabIiwiw7hCRcOeZlPIpz0iLCJuJFwiYCUgLT4gJWAkJTtcXFxuaiIsIltbXV1cbltbXSxbXV1cbltbW1tdXSxbW10sW1tdXV0sW11dLFtdXVxuW1tbW11dXV1cbltdXG5dXG5bW11bXV1cblssXVxuLFxuW10sW11cbltbW11dW1tdXV1cbltbXSxdXG4sW10iXQ==)

Still shorter than JavaScript! The link is a test suite, hence the additional flags - those are just to wrap all inputs into a list (`a`) and to treat all inputs as strings (`S with updot` - it's the equivalent of wrapping every input in quotation marks).

### Explained

```
øBEÞfSȧ=
øBE      # wrap the input in square brackets and try to evaluate it as a python literal
   Þf    # attempt to flatten the list by a level - if the input was listlike (that is, valid for this challenge or valid as a python tuple), this will undo the `øB`. Otherwise it leaves the string as is
     S   # convert the result of the above to string. The P flag makes it so that square brackets and commas are used for lists instead of the angular brackets and pipes Vyxal uses.
      ȧ= # remove any whitespace and test to see if this new string is equal to the original input.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 101 bytes

```
\(x,y='',s=\(p,b,x)sub(p,b,x,,,T)){while(y!=(y=x)){x=s('[[],[]','[[]',y);x=s('[[]]','[]',x)};y=='[]'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZA9DsIwDIX3nKJMSZDZkSrfgq1EqEWpQOpQNalIhHoSljIwcqDehvwCXeKXz3nPch7PYV7eehjlSUulVYHFmdGqEoIC8RW-0kMIxInA172kBeWEtHWnVok5LjsgFIgOl5NihAhJeXZ8lLsxGV-jbnf7RR6ZAYuUgsIj66EBw9XYRAUAB87vt8u1k8xukFk07m5QsbSUm-0TwfIy08DcYfhUWkSvpzRsq-q-7yz7fRS0nCT4t6yj0THPsX4A)

Text replacement solution,
'[[],[]' -> '[[]'
'[[]]' -> '[]'

Earlier attempts at this were using far too many `\\` to escape `[`/`]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
{Times=N}~Block~ToExpression@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCsIwEITveYwUelqfQCpF0aMo9lZ6CGFLQ38iTQpC2Lx6tKkRvOwMM/Oxo7AdjsIqKUJbBFepEU1xJX8ctOx9pc@v54zGKD2VWR7ui0Jb3mY12TrbHU4dyr5uy2xfzQvCRQwGmyb3Dykm7xh3johDVPjZNYSYfEzM/7uvXy/jCU8LiALbAlzCiCKZfm2j1BJnxMIb)

Uses `{,}`. Returns by presence/absence of an error.

Missing arguments are interpreted as `Null`, but will raise an error message.

Juxtaposition is a valid operation (`Times`), so we use `Block` to turn it into `N`. Since `N` only handles one or two arguments, it errors when passed three or more arguments. When `N` has exactly two arguments, the second argument must be of the form `precision` or `{precision,accuracy}`, where `precision` and `accuracy` are numbers. Input is guaranteed to never have numbers, so the 2-argument form is also guaranteed to error.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) (compile-time), 43 bytes

```rust
macro_rules!v{([$($a:tt),*])=>($(v!{$a})*)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyotLvn/PzcxuSg/vqg0J7VYsaxaI1pFQyXRqqREU0crVtPWTkNFo0yxWiWxVlNLs/Y/kBkdHasDxrFgXMtVUJqkkJankJuYmaehqVBd@x8A)

This is a Rust macro (the compile-time equivalent of a function) named `v!`. Use as `v!{…}`, where `…` is the string you want to check (without delimiters – string literals are opaque to the usual sort of Rust macro). I used `[`, `,`, `]` as in the question, although this could easily be adapted to use almost any Rust token in place of `,` and/or `()` rather than `[]`.

Outputs via error/non-error: an invalid list causes a compile time error, a valid list causes no error (and the macro expands to an empty declaration).

### Explanation

```rust
macro_rules!v{([$($a:tt),*])=>($(v!{$a})*)}
macro_rules!v{                            }   Macro declaration
              ([          ])                  Match something surrounded by []
                $(     ) *                      which consists of 0 or more
                  $a:tt                         balanced token trees $a
                        ,                       separated by commas
                            =>(          )    and replace it with,
                               $(   $a )*       for each $a,
                                 v!{$a}         a recursive call to v!{$a}
```

We verify the structure of the outermost list, then recurse into the inner lists to make sure that those are also correct. Rust macros have a `:tt` builtin that matches brackets, which makes it easy to use the strategy of parsing out the elements first and recursing over them afterwards. The base case of the recursion is that when we match a zero-length list, the replacement expands into zero macro calls, because the loop in the replacement runs for zero iterations.

Note that Rust normally allows a trailing comma on lists, so we do actually have to write our own verification macro rather than using something that Rust has predefined.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell (GHCi), 0 bytes

Takes input from `stdin`, returns truthy iff `stderr` is empty.

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet either of the allowed output formats, since neither the truthy nor falsy values are consistent.

Comment: The program outputs "one consistent value representing either truthy or falsy, and anything else as the other" as the rules stay: empty `stderr` represents truthy, anything else (non-empty `stderr`) represents falsy.

Comment: I guess the question is whether you are allowed to ignore the non-stderr output.  Because at current neither is consistent *unless* you only look at output from stderr.  The question is at least a bit unclear as to whether this is allowed, unless there is some meta-consensus I am missing.

Comment: Well, since programs may output to stderr, and I'm stating that the program outpus to stderr, I don't see why one should look to the things that the program outputs via other I/O methods

Comment: Moreover, the challenge explicitly states "Output by erroring/not erroring is allowed"

Comment: That does not seem clear from the challenge to me.  But I asked the OP so we'll get a clear answer eventually.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `json.reader`, 5 bytes

```
json>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xDgIhDIZ3nqK5mTg4auJqXFyME2EgXC@iF7gr4MUYnx2ht9zS9v/@tmkHY1Ogcr9drucDPGPwO0LTI8FEmNJnIucT2OCT89kkF3yEiHNGbzHCvMALyeMILsBRiHn5CqW0bkGuuUnJshYMN0YrtOB2hlILKXhUsM89vKwaFf5AgSrtylPpKUzQJcrYwXqlru5@xYMZ44YT2vCuP2lAYx/lDw)

Outputs by the presence of an error.

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://rust-lang.org), 406 bytes

```
fn a(d:&str)->bool{let c=d.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>();let c=c.as_slice();let b=c.iter().fold((0,0),|mut a,&i|{if i=='['{a.0+=1}else if i==']'{a.1+=1}a});let m=c.windows(2).any(|a|a[0]==']'&&a[1]=='[');let mut j=false;c.iter().fold(0,|a,&i|{if i=='['{a+1}else if i==']'{a-1}else if i==','&&a==0{j=true;a}else{a}});let o=c.windows(3).find(|a|a[1]==','&&(a[0]!=']'||a[2]!='['));b.0==b.1&&!m&&!j&&o.is_none()}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3e6a38be3206b06750a387eb52281d5f)

Not a golfing language by any means, but it's worth giving it a try.
It can be golfed down a lot as it's currently using a really naïve approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„,]å≠i.E}˜
```

No error as truthy; error (`** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for ...`) as falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8ndjDSx91LsjUc609Pef/fyUlpejoWJ1YIA0A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLjufx/1DBPJ/bw0kedCzL1XGtPz/lve2h9YKaSX75CalFRfpHS4dVKXK5BQf5Bikq1Ooe22f@PVoqOjo1V0gFROjAWSEgHLABkgIVRpCBMIKGgBNUJldUBkTpgSZ1oqPrYWLAWqA1gBVCpWKVYAA). (Wrap the single TIO input in `"""` quotes to get the input as string, instead of implicitly as (possibly faulty) list.)

**Explanation:**

```python
     i  }   # If
            # the (implicit) input-string
    ≠       # does NOT
   å        # contain the substring
„,]         # ",]":
      .E    #  Evaluate the (implicit) input-string as Elixir
            # (implicit else)
            #  (implicitly use the input-string)
         ˜  # Flatten (results in [] for lists; or an error for strings)
```

The if-statement is for edge-case `[[],]`, which unfortunately is a valid Elixir/Python list that evaluates to `[[]]`. If it wasn't for this test cases, `.E˜` would have been enough in the new version of 05AB1E: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX6nDpeRfWgLj/ddzPT3nv@2h9YGZSn75CqlFRflFSodXK3G5BgX5Bykq1eoc2mb/P1opOjo2VkkHROnAWCAhHbAAkAEWRpGCMIGEghJUJ1RWB0TqgCV1oqHqY2PBWqA2gBVApWKVYgE).
And it could even have been 1 [byte](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) in the [legacy version of 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b) using the `-e`/`--eval` flag: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ZU4xDsIwENvziuPEGCgIsaAKFspIRdeqQ0ojNRJqopKCGPgJP2Bg4wEw8qhAAy1BTGeffT6nbJubNdMwhbXMeF9uWSo4@D4E4YJgsGObimmegShUpSeAM0owrPSHmMfJzG@XlaC4lMDLUpZ4PyMJoiiMOnikt@uM1Elkn4sNh5KzOopkkgCog85lMQJPKu0Nxiwdcu/9v68OP3V6dSMfuvay4AYR4zhJXoO8IXVZLVG7fAEr/clf2gAnzDHTBtHWT2MnKklsmlOkPXBsFj0B).

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 31 bytes

```
{($^a~~/"["<~~>*%",""]"/)~~$^a}
```

This is a function which takes the string as input and produces typical Raku Booleans (`True` or `False`).

Let's break it down. First, better spacing

```
{ ($^a ~~ /"[" <~~> * % "," "]"/) ~~ $^a}
```

First, `$^a` is a sort of special syntax for declaring lambdas without explicitly mentioning their arguments, so this is equivalent to the single-argument function

```
-> $a { ($a ~~ /"[" <~~> * % "," "]"/) ~~ $a}
```

Now, `~~` is a terribly clever thing in Raku called the smart-match operator. At a high-level, it's going to evaluate its right-hand side and then call the `.ACCEPTS` method on the right-hand side with the left-hand side as argument. We use it twice here: The leftmost application is on a regex object and will do a regular expression match. The rightmost application is on the input string and will perform ordinary string equality.

We're going to do a regex match against that regular expression enclosed in `/`. That match will return either a special regex `Match` object, or `Nil` if the match fails. We then compare that for string equality. A `Match` object stringifies as the substring it matched, so we're simply checking whether the match that was found is in fact the *whole* string. `Nil`, on the other hand, stringifies to `""`, and as per the comments the empty string is not valid input, so `$^a` will never compare equal to that.

Now let's look at the regex itself.

```
/"[" <~~> * % "," "]"/
```

If you haven't seen Raku regexes before, it may be best to forget everything you know about regular expressions, because the syntax is only superficially similar. Anything enclosed is quotes is matched literally, so `"["`, `","`, and `"]"` are matched literally. `*` works like it does in most regex languages: It's the Kleene star and matches zero or more. `%` is a modifier on `*` which delimits multiple matches by the thing on its right (in our case, a comma). Finally, `<~~>` is the recursive matcher, which matches the entire regular expression again. So, in summary

```
/                      # Start of regex
 "["                   # Match an opening bracket
          *            # Then match zero or more...
            % ","      # delimited by commas...
     <~~>              # of the current regular expression recursively
                  "]"  # Finally, match a closing bracket
                     / # End of regex
```

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 84 bytes

```
	L ='[]' | ('[' *L ARBNO(',' *L) ']')
	INPUT POS(0) L RPOS(0)	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NHwVY9OlZdoUZBQz1aXUHLR8ExyMnPX0NdB8TRVFCPVdfk4vT0CwgNUQjwD9Yw0FTwUQiCsDit3DRc/VyA8v6hISAFtoZcQP7//zrRsQA)

Prints 1 for truthy and nothing for falsey.

Recursive pattern matching is pretty slick.

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##dZCxCsMgEIZn8xS3nRaHFjoFMqREaUFMMDoUcelcmqFr392atBQS7SDnfXf89989H9Ntuh9jJJ2QFy0oSmoZMlKnUEmioEEfEF5A0SPsFLTmpHuKfE4YYEBWEQtDP9I9AwXm8yO1pEZYZ3QqS2gOSfCbR0t6Zwdnk7Q1zp6vNVY/JOk8j62BD9yHnCaeCn55YWn525bjFUDZqlFsjRR8FPT5lvBsFC@slJQWY4VdM8HSRRIRuotv).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>79</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>eval("r=/(<(<>,)+<>>)|(<<>>)/;r.test(s)&&f(s.replace(r,'<>'))||s=='<>'")
```

uses the characters `<,>` and returns `true`/`false`

saved 1 byte thanks to @RadvylfPrograms
saved 1 byte by using recursion and joining expressions

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tU@7boQwEKzjr7BOp2OtONDnbH9JCixio4ssjLy@a4BvJ3hJwaVIl2afM7OzX/ZhsUu3Mb8N8dOtXq@ojXvYAKekG1CgjBSvyhgxgyqpuaY6O8yA4nLxgHVyY7CdgyQrZSoh5hm1LuVJrDndHXLN20JlW5B7Lq2kditoeFiUwrQ1juGWofoYKnFl3gbclUiGwNIwyUiSEY@4dGRb0PC3CuvigDG4OsQeqmKOd7boYrYp052YoHzHo@dkXkzs5chqz1PZL@/8PHmCiqXdiE3zDOvhBygKsj8gl2cX9NlfNvbX/8HH@g0)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! I think you can save a few bytes with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55618/79857) trick, and possibly more with recursion.

Comment: Also, this seems to give `false` for `<<<<>>,<<>,<<>>>,<>>,<>` which is in the truthy cases section, not sure if that's an issue with this answer or the test cases.

Comment: I think that’s an issue with the case. if you count up the pairs on that one, you are missing a closing bracket. it should be `<<<<>>,<<>,<<>>>,<>>,<>>`. (Note the final ending `>`

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
Ｆθ≔⪫⪪⪫⪪θ[[]]¦[]¦[[],[¦[[θ⁼θ[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBo1BTwbG4ODM9T8MrPzNPI7ggJ7MEmVmoo6AUHR0bq6QJYkCp6FidaCgLRBVqWnMFFGXmlWi4FpYm5hRDNAHValr//x8NVAQyQAesC8gAkhCsFPtftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for valid, nothing for invalid. Explanation: Boring port of @recursive's Stax answer.

```
Ｆθ
```

Repeat more than enough times...

```
≔⪫⪪⪫⪪θ[[]]¦[]¦[[],[¦[[θ
```

... remove the first or only element of a list if it's an empty list.

```
⁼θ[]
```

Check that we're left with an empty list.

Less boring 34 byte solution:

```
›⬤⁺,θ№,[[]],⁺ι§⁺θ,κ⊙θ∧κ⁼№…θκ[№…θκ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU67CsMwDPwVo0kB9Qs6GVNKt@zGg0kMCRFO7Txovt5VHOjSA91wd5KuG3zuZs@ltHmMKz5z8GvIqJmx5W1BICCVGlJm3sQHsta5U6vuSEqvr9iHz5VOpGRB0lMjEDMep6ZjjxOpR9o8L3hdMkfHwQzz@wxMkgULvzf/poOm4l6KBWtrC6FaR/gacOW28xc) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for valid, nothing for invalid. Explanation:

```
   ,                                Literal string `,`
  ⁺                                 Concatenated with
    θ                               Input string
 ⬤                                  All characters satisfy
      ,[[]],                        Literal string `,[[]],`
     №                              Contains
             ι                      Current character
            ⁺                       Concatenated with
                θ                   Input string
               ⁺                    Concatenated with
                 ,                  Literal string `,`
              §                     Indexed by
                  κ                 Current index
›                                   And not
                    θ               Input string
                   ⊙                All characters satisfy
                      κ             Current index
                     ∧              Logical And
                        №           Count of
                            [       Literal string `[`
                         …θκ        In current prefix
                       ⁼            Equals
                             №      Count of
                                 ]  Literal string `]`
                              …θκ   In current prefix
                                    Implicitly print
```

Note that by default Charcoal tries to parse an input in a JSON-like format so to defeat that you need to wrap the input in JSON i.e. prepend `["` and append `"]`.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 178 bytes

```c
int v(char *s){int d=1;for(s++;*s!='\0';s++){if(d==0)return 0;if(*s=='{')d++;if(*s=='}'){d--;if(*(s+1)=='{')return 0;}if(*s==','&&!(*(s-1)=='}'&&*(s+1)=='{'))return 0;}return!d;}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for the input `,}`, it assumes the first character is a `{`.

Comment: oh shit, I was sure I checked for this. oh well, next time then.