# Is it a circumfix?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, subsequence

### Introduction

We all know prefixes and suffixes. But there are other types of affixes that exist too. Such as circumfixes, a type of affix that has two parts, one of which is a prefix and another of which is a suffix. Figuring out whether some string is a prefix or a suffix of some other string is easy, but what about figuring out whether it might be a circumfix?

That is today's challenge - create a program or function which takes two strings as input, and determine whether the first is a circumfix of the second.

For the purposes of this challenge a string `i1` is a circumfix of another string `i2` if and only if there exists some non-empty string `j` which is a contiguous substring of `i2` such that removing `j` from `i2` results in `i1`, and `j` is neither a prefix nor a suffix of `i2` (if it is, you don't have a circumfix, you just have a suffix or a prefix respectively).

For example, `"fog"` is a circumfix of `"frog"`, because removing `"r"` from `"frog"` produces `"fog"`.

When given valid input, your program either needs to output a single consistent value of your choice if the first input string is a circumfix of the second, and any other value if it is not, or vice versa. For example, you may decide have your program output `6` when the first string is a circumfix of the second, in which case *any* output except `6` is acceptable when it is not.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so do make sure to golf your code.

### Test cases

```
Format:
"String 1", "String 2" -> output
    comments about the test case - in all these test cases, the output will be true if string 1 is a circumfix or string 2 and false otherwise
```

```
"apply", "appreciably" -> true
    "app]reciab[ly"
"rake", "racket by the lake" -> true
    multiple options - "r]acket by the l[ake" and "ra]cket by the la[ke"
"trout", "trumpet" -> false
    Doesn't work at all
"bring", "brought him a gong" -> false
    You only get to remove one substring - "br]ought h[i]m a go[ng" is not allowed
"falcon", "false conundrum" -> false
    You can't have extra stuff at the start or end either - "fal]se [con(undrum)" is not allowed
"goose", "goosebumps" -> false
    "goose]bumps[" is just a prefix
"lame", "blame" -> false
    And "]b[lame" is just a suffix
"pale", "pale ale" -> true
    "pale] ale[" is just a prefix, but "pal]e al[e" is a circumfix, so this is allowed
"b", "barb" -> false
    This could be a prefix ("b]arb[") or a suffix ("]bar[b"), but not a circumfix - "b]ar[b" is not allowed
"abba", "aba" -> false
    "abba" can be split into a prefix of "aba" ("ab") and a suffix of "aba" ("ba"), but "abba" is still not a circumfix of "aba"
"friend", "friend" -> false
    It's only a proper circumfix if you actually remove something - "fri][end" doesn't make the cut
"float", "on" -> false
    You may not assume the first input will be shorter than the second one
"", "" -> false
    One or both input strings may be empty
"Twin Sister", "Twister" -> false
    Inputs are ordered - you may reverse the order, but there must be a consistent ordering
"case", "Castle" -> false
    Inputs are case sensitive
"<<@ 23|>", "<<@23??|> 23|>" -> true
    "<<@]23??|>[ 23|>", not all characters will be letters)
```

Comment: Are empty inputs possible?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, one or both inputs may be empty

Answer (score 13):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>23</s></sup> <sup><s>21</s></sup> 20 bytes

```
>&#*]e.1}:@}.-&#]\.[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBLa8MwEITv@RVLAxENjcnjZhInEOipp7a3NoeVIz8a2TKSQgkkv91dr3qQD4LZmU/SSD/9UyIK2KUg4AWWkNJaJHB8f3vts9l0flLJ6pEeHsliNj19J1/980TllYEV7EBg11mV1yj1TUABbJCMCIv5RXmQN/CVAo0XNYBkDyJwy4Hz9tp0ynPorbl6EYWSjLLyUNUNIJSmLZmTtiYVcQVqpyA37bU903kMkUdGTJXGOCXpOscAj6PbNDahJYvoMR1qBbQ4HIbRNrQy1IpdlMgmShJxVVur9hwaBhmF1JcDbXD0D@xGBojP39p5ZTkg3cJHmKNNR3T@v3KObvSe7faw3uz39wzWm3vGCFlhmPR/)

*-1 byte thanks to Bubbler*

Return true if:

- `>&#` left arg is strictly longer than right (see the "friend"/"friend" test case)
- `*` and...
- `]` the right arg
- `e.` is an element of the list formed by...
- `1 }:@}.` removing the first and last elements of...
- `-&# ]\. [` all the [outfixes](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/bslashdot#dyadic) `\.` of the left arg `[` whose size is the difference in size between the two args `-&#`

That is, J has a builtin to subtract the "chunks" in the middle of the necessary size and leave us with the remaining prefixes and suffixes, catted.  We simply have to remove the non-proper ones (ie, the first and last elements of the list of outfixes), and check for what we're searching for.

Comment: +1 for the perfect use case of outfix.

Comment: `1}:@}.` in place of `[:}:@}.` saves a byte. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBLa8MwEITv@RVLAxENjcnjZhInEOipp7a3NoeVIz8a2TKSQgkkv91dr3qQD4LZmU/SSD/9UyIK2KUg4AWWkNJaJHB8f3vts9l0flLJ6pEeHsliNj19J1/980TllYEV7EBg11mV1yj1TUABbJCMCIv5RXmQN/CVAo0XNYBkDyJwy4Hz9tp0ynPorbl6EYWSjLLyUNUNIJSmLZmTtiYVcQVqpyA37bU903kMkUdGTJXGOCXpOscAj6PbNDahJYvoMR1qBbQ4HIbRNrQy1IpdlMgmShJxVVur9hwaBhmF1JcDbXD0D@xGBojP39p5ZTkg3cJHmKNNR3T@v3KObvSe7faw3uz39wzWm3vGCFlhmPR/ "J – Try It Online")

Comment: @Bubbler thanks and nice catch.  updated.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>86</strike> <strike>84</strike> <strike>83</strike> <strike>80</strike> <strike>77</strike> 76 bytes

```
lambda a,b:len(a)<len(b)*any(a==b[:i]+b[i-len(a):]for i in range(1,len(a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcmxCoUwDEDR3a8ITsmzDuJWXr9EHBKsGqhRiotfXxFxuhfOcZ3rbn0pCQIk3mRiYCc@RUOm/xOhH9uFHIIMXsdGBm1f9uO8Z1BQg8y2ROzcC0TVkdVOTFjPWaNNtfuGqJQb)

-2 bytes thanks to [@Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) whitespace before and after `==`

-1 byte remove whitespace.

-3 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) using any to write for loop in one line.

-3 bytes by replacing `and` with `*`

-1 byte by replacing def with lambda

## Python3.8, 71 bytes

```
lambda a,b:(c:=len(a))<len(b)*any(a==b[:i]+b[i-c:]for i in range(1,c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcYxDoMwDADAva/wht2mA2KpouYliMEOobVETWQxwOtTdeh0V8/9vdnwqN7aAQlW/sjMwEEi5pjWYshEz59CV7YTOSUZo043GfWe47RsDgpq4Gyvgn3IRJfqajse2C2uxeYu/EPU2hc)

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! Since the goal is to have a smaller byte count, you will want to remove the whitespace in your `a == b...` check.

Comment: I put your 3.8 code into a shell and got a SyntaxError.

Comment: @AlexHall fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 17 bytes

```
^(.+)(.+)¶\1.+\2$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BasNADEXX0ilm0UJKIFBnG5JCj5AuQ6nkyOMh4xkzI1MMOVcP0Iu5crrQ@18f9FVEQ6LleXP@guVzs9u@rPP7c3ndbS/N07LQOMYZjEXaQBxnLHQTKNTeRB3PTntx0SLUkicFLdMwiiKXkDywZb5X14fBkfM5eewotjmBSRVnbkpXO0GfcxV4kK2hYqRBgFfiSFFghbNBBqbCSMwExIRdCZKu8C/YxUwKOeHHd0juHKpKAfOrYkv2452qWs3h8Oaa/f0IZpr96XQ/PtY/) Link includes test suite that takes each test on its own line with the test values separated by a tab and converts them into individual tests with the values on separate lines as the main program expects.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
~c₃{b&}ᵐ↺b↺c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY@xboMwEIZf5eShU9SBrFFSqY/Qbojh7DhgxWBkjGiUpEMrRXTrW7RjlwzN2DeBF6F3Tga4//9@m/@QHlWxsy5Ppn3RCTANiG61H08/49v7cO7/fsf@W1QuED6O/ZdAUMarttyYF3AbPhw6cS@Gy8dxOH9Or4ru7eUdm/F0kfSoaUpTgXVtd2LG02tlUJLLZqnwuNWEaY2tDiB3EAoNliGnwbs2UBx8W9Y6RCa9qXJikrK8CFCYEhByR5DjDVrlKspJNBpIt9Warscwd67hujglfbOJ2GLJVMbJoEbLgAewjL18Ar2MBqVE/ht6x1JvdLXm0quIzDrk3WkZtqTifO5MBU@mCdoTIhcVJwrjbo/YhFvlYvEAyfywJEoyma9Wh@UVZNk/)

Takes string 1 (the possible circumfix) through the output variable, string 2 through the input variable, and outputs through success or failure.

<s>I recall that at some point my original solution could be [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY@xTsMwEIZf5eSBqWJo16pB4hFgqzKcXTex6sSR4yhEaRlAQmXjDTpSNpYOMPImzYuEO7eL//@@38l/lh5V3lmXTcc@bwWYGkSb9MPb9/Dyej7t/36G/VGULhDeDftPgaCMV02xNk/g1nw5tOJWnH/fd@fTx/isennDbjgccxWGw9c4LpcCq8p2YsLqtTIoaUonS@FxownTEhsdQHYQcg2WIafBuyZQHHxTVDpEJr0pM2KSsiwPkJsCEDJHkOM1WuVKysnUGsg35Yo@j2HmXM11USX9s47YYsFURmVQoWXAAmxjL99AL@OAUiK/hs5Y6o0uV1x6MZFZh7w7LcMjuaiPrSnhwdRBe0I0RceJwrjbPdbhWjmf38F0tl0QJTudJcl2cQFp@g8), but as of now subscriptless `c` seems to cycle through all partitions infinitely, causing false test cases to not terminate</s> except it would also cause false positives where the two inputs are equal.

(I tried golfing `{b&}ᵐ` to `Xz∧X` (when it's already a shorter alternative to `{l>0&}ᵐ`), but it has a false positive for the empty test case, since there's no problem cycling an empty list to the length of the longest when everything is empty.)

```
~c₃             Split the input variable into three parts, such that
   {  }ᵐ        each of them
    b&          can have its first element removed (i.e. it is not empty).
        ↺       Rotate the list of partitions left,
         b      remove the first element (which was in the middle),
          ↺     and rotate the remaining partitions again.
           c    Do they concatenate to the output variable?
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
⁻ȧŒṖḢ;ṪƊ€iɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY@9TsNAEIRf5eQ6VVISJUiUlNAgy8Wec9hHzj86n4UspYGSkgIQEg1NJMQDEEGHEsFjOC9iZjcU9sx@c@dZXxnnumHY33z@rLf3/eah/3g96jdvu7v97bv9fRz6zTPc93r3Atl@8ZknuFM8F8MQxxHVteuiEas3qSWNKRnFkaelAfaULk1QulMhN8ox5DT4qg2Ig2@L2gRh2tsyA9PIsjyo3BaKVFYBcnxJLq1K5DCNUfBtucB1CbOqarhOVOObjWBHBVMtyqAmx4BFsZVePkFey0BaE/8N3lLqrSkXXHowwlxFvDuW4RFO9PzalurMNsF4IEziOElJdjuhJvxXTqfHajxZzUBhx5P5fDU7gCT5Aw)

Takes string 1 (the potential circumfix) as the right/second argument, string 2 as the left/first argument, and outputs 0 if it's not a circumfix and a positive integer otherwise.

(The test footer is bad, but it's better than nothing.)

```
⁻              The arguments are not equal,
 ȧ             and
          ɗ    you also get a truthy value from the next three links:
         i     the index of the right argument (defaulting to 0) in
  ŒṖ           the list of all partitions of the left argument
        €      with each partition mapped to
    Ḣ;ṪƊ       the concatenation of its first and last elements.
```

Although this is mostly just a translation of my Brachylog answer, `ŒṖ` cannot generate empty elements of partitions while `c` is obligated to, so prefixes and suffixes are naturally accounted for.

This 15-byte monstrosity is what I had before I just tried putting the `⁻` at the start of the program... and before I realized I could use `Ḣ;Ṫ`: `ŒṖ1,0ịFƊ€⁸ṭṚi>1`

Answer (score 6):

## Regex ([POSIX ERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) or better), 17 bytes

Takes the two strings in joined format, delimited by a single newline.

```
^(.+)(.+)
\1.+\2$
```

Turned out to be identical to [Neil's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194937/17216), so I'm mainly answering this to demonstrate it in a wide range of regex engines:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXbbuM2EH3PV0y9RSTmouxmiz6s10mLbgu0D12gyUuhqAAl0RYTShTIURxtt9@ezpCKHSdeA7YoDuecMzf6Vt5LXznd46nvda1ca7s7NT66RafW8Jda/frQp@mXxcXZ0eM/aXYs@Htw8y47vjn//vHo7IvI0F6h090qFZk3ulLpjyenPwgxX1qX6sXbeWoWTsna6E6lQny36AZj5nrxTvyrl6kWPfliKuYHJjOqW2FzeGjyt8VikcySw8N@QI8uTf@4@vxn1kvnVZrkybHJnOqNJLKzN9nR2UmSiOOkSER2a3WXJjddIkTWSqya1InL5NoN6gNA8iH5TRpPy0TMJ2Qj5v89zmTfm3F2ArxwqtKypFeYPm8AyR9SNhbRmpNZHMycvFPs5WR1pxDKEbBRYHh369YOBnVvFNgete08nJJDseuRBxfZ1YxV7ILlZCIudHZAJiPUtle4kRclLjkwSD9Z5bsEYW3dHUgEaQz5llwf9i0JZNUgNLoFCStLu1vfv@0AtjMjrIgeLTjV2nuS3SnwQ@lDkVl86YoJJddFxMkZSHvobKC0a1UTLeFWtmPeyEAvQ1eT/NlzyUxbSRbdSKJTD@gkeByWSw6Ac@BROgTrQFGClKYtxzrIvyCAnGDTiCv2iFhZ60ORwqKk3PnZ67xFaxHMeUC5HTzBALXDUj8QjpFtgCnDAnY/G5yfuYQF9Uc4tIXxFE6A6aUJMPwEXu/CTJ3G1oLNe7ScQDlgACgYIY88EirtqqENB7ylvNEm728SUQb10pUvxe8EcM1@lR1MDaXacJKksiDXfCa4Dk/x0HZBiHk5E1FVSP1WSeiWIhx4XRhZljKMHD2@rSce4wZhPb43GoEuDLuVZpcTBp8lfTxFG4HPjPQ7qZwwSZFHbcwr1U9O3MJOU9OFFo6rvSJ/x8TH0WFVtqf@3KLpJYzU4rLCgYIfn8bK21ZRkeJIEXiRB/h6GuCWboTQ/NWArMNYGaaf5unbyeJRauUYA/J@aCPEUjvPWaMrD9YcMGeysQ5JJzaU2TBkiuao5mknOmba1ya7dJ/pZqBuKC02E3q8JHwQQSSq7XEkuOu17uBKeyJkZHoNy5dZZAjqWMeo9FekakrNOIXk1L2i2z9IDdZYSr4LFLQ8H6FdKQbP4B3GU6SG@CsZr4BfpEfzcnj38bMDZYSwUN9zQj5@/AnO33@9YBRan7@/vPx6EXeejS1ZimjKn05PPQ9VI@lfgqL2mxIYhfwu/gc) - ECMAScript (SpiderMonkey)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVdb9s4EHzPr1ioh8q6OGqTvsV1cof7ANqHK3DJy0HRoZRE20woUUdScYy2vz03S/ojThwDtikud2a4nKVuxb1wtVW9P@lMIx@dF9bLZvp@Yqd/y/kfD/3oylvVzXMrll8f/x3lxxl/j25O8@Obs58ev@ZOq1qOTscnp1k2sfK/QVk5Sq0UjVadTLO8xtjLT52Xdiaw9Jvq@sGf99bU0rnc@UZ1P7LcdKM0ZIz19OLbEdFaC719S0/WmsHnS6s8OG66NJtslk1PJ8jRxftyOk2T9NWsz1df/sp7YR0AivRY51b2mmW9e5P//G6cptlxWkL1rVFdpMhb4evFyGaXybUd5DlRcp78KbTDMMmY9SCRziY/ssdE9L1eJWPigZW1EhUeaf15Qx6INOJgGaMFwtlRYsWd5Cwr6jvpqVqRX0jSPLtLawftVa8lmd4r0zk6QUK5n1GEFNE1jFXugxUIgctbqGYyoLa99Ft5UeKMt0qj3410XeppaewdCU9Ca@RWbA7OrQAyX3haqJYEzQ1md7n/mIFMp1c0B703ZGVr7iG7k@SGygWHsfjKlmuUQpURp2Ag5agzgdIsZQNa4NamY97IgIehayA/eSqZaWvBohcCdPLBWwG/DLMZb4BrEMxDxpJEgaTClGUdyC8BUAB2FHGzAyLmxrhwSGFQoXYueVm3GC1DuAgot4MDDFwjZ@oBOFq0AaYKA9r/bHF@5SMs4Y@waAfjsJ0A0wsdYPifeLwPs3YaR0sOH9AypmrwAaBkhCLyCKqVrYc2LHAGdcMkz28LUQX1wlbPxe9t4JrzajPohiq55YSkqkRqkWR8Dpv9YLoEYlElWVQVSr9TEtxShgUvD0ZUlQgth7/X9cRlbBDW43qtPKkO7txKM7M1Bq@FPu6ircAnQfyuVa4xoch5pfUL1ZsktrBVMF2wcBwdFPnJpy62DqsyPfy5Q1MzWsHiovYDNr/atJUzrcQhxZYCeFkE@GbdwC1uhGD@evCsQxsRuh/99HqxuJVasYobcm5oI8RMWcdVw4VOS94wV3JhcCFbxFHZ0GQSfdRwt4OOmQ7ZZJ/uC24GuKEyfrFGj5eECyJAItverwB3vVQdXSkHQkbGYxg@ryJDwLGWURtp8VY5CaVjNCvvJV4HQWqIxqPku0BSy/0R7Io9OAbvfFwFNeCvRbwCfhPO6@fNe4ifE1ARYHl1zwX5@PEXOvvw/YJRMD77cHn5/SLOPGlbRMoYKjar156neiHwlsCu3fYItPT8nP0P) - ECMAScript 2018 (Node.js)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVNb9s4EL3nVwxcAbK2qR2n2EucjwabXWD30B6ay0LRGpRM22ooUSGppIbr/vXsG1K248Q1kJjkzLz3ZjhDN9Ko359bK@mfr18@j6laUmTGtFK6EIqi4Rjbi/Ob69vry/XRTJt@VF6cjM8vx/geJSsqZzhJVo0pa0e9u7o3XlOk6IJsm1sH98nxh9HxKJEPbKSrF@cnsCR0RtFkfEQAov7GpmDjkLgXJ6voAWiRghAsfpIdvhv8NmRdAudTWeipnHyzuqY4jQfRwyDO4s74aRWJdXqSDZh6EHajbExBbL/PTj9pGJlhchXfmlaeEcVn8V9CWSzjZLyGruDM/OvJ5M/PN5PJ83/9wfuE/47uRoP3d6fR83NPNI1a9o6JF0YWpcixpe7zjhzQqc/GLFhTmJOjnhH3kqOMKO6lo3xJbiFJ8ekurGqVKxslSTeu1LWlDwjI9iNSHyLqKWNl@2ApTOByRreOyYBaNdJt5QWJM06b@jda2jp29KTNPQlHQinE5qjCnGNzgMwXjhZlRYLmGqe72H91S7pWS5qD3mkystKPkF3L7toBwuJzk3UoaZkFnJSBSku19pT6SU5BC9xC18wbGLBp6ynk915KZtpCsOiFAJ387owg69rZjBPgGlgnjCNtSKJAssSRYR2IzwCQArYfcJMDIuZaW39JfpGjdrb3tm7Bmnlz6lG@tRYwaCA5K78DR4nKw@R@QfufLc41X2GG/vBOOxiLdDxMI5SH4W/i9T5M12lszdh8QMsx5a3zABkjpIFHUFGaoq28g9WoGw75fFuI3KsXJn8tfi@BW44rdKumlMstJyTlGULTXsL3sMkHxxkQ07yXBFW@9Dslvlsy7/D2YkSeCz9y@Pq1nuDGDcJ6bKNKRxhpvZOmZx0G@0IfT9FW4Asj/ncqO0wosq5U6o3qTRC3sCnRdL6Fw@qgyL9dbMPosCrdoD93aHgal2hxUbgWyS83Y2V1JXFJYaQAnqUeftoNcIUXwTd/0TrWobTw0495@nWxeJQqsQwJWdtWAWJWGstVa5D7EyfMlVxo46DTLVBZP2R4i1E5TDvomOlQm@zTfcHLgG7ItVt06OGRsF4ESGTVuCXgbp/Kmr6WFoSMjK1fvq4iQ6BjDaNOpZFTlGbZpWTkozQ25OOt4Sr5LZBU8Xz4dkUOlsFrF7ygBvyFCE/AH8I69Xp4D/FzACoCLFc@ckHOzz/R6ccfl4yC9enHq6sfl@HkxdjCkgVTuvHuep6KhcCvBLK22ytQ0vE@@R8) - Perl 5
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZVvb9s2EMbf51PcWKOWWsf503dxXG9Y0yLA0Axp3gyyJlAyHSmhRIGkkhprP3v2HOXYcZIGcEzxeL977ngnt2X7cDpry5YGlqYkDgSNqbXqOrOq1bJQ0fBg/G6WZaXUPitM3VZa2Xk0jyfzywM3HNEQnyU2s2vFBxqvGu@iLPt8/tdZlsUjOoqBFAedmOwtjY0G1fRwMtDTJc676NvVp/Ov8ST@j6plNNCJ81arBqt4/yidTsW8ETEOuy6HBdujw9H@UTwJp6tYFaXhIxMC9WiyR9inaMt4@xbIQ3CGYogQg3oaUqulL8poYEc3pmoiBoxunGmyhSrMQkUiEeNnJXgzfncwHCFVQMciFXEMDRy9r5WWzmfKWqQX/zb9@/LsS/b1Iju7vLy4nIkz3j8hcRIN6pm4sp06ITyJz1I7LAVIP6E80MRAi8nPZ9WO4snDv9H4fcyfvfnR@P38ePDwIGTb6pUYES@sKiqZ45HWf2/IIxJFbEx7awJzvCesvFXsZWVxqzzlK/KlIs27W7e6075qtSLT@so0jvbhkO56JMFFNgtmpbuwBCbE8tZ0noOBWrfKb@T1EpdcAoo@GeWaoad7Y29JepJawze3VXPNvjkg16WnsqpJ0rXB7tb3H9ORafSK0E7kDVlVmzvIbhT1TQMIi89tuqYkVdpzEgZVjhoTQpp7tUBYcNHFHLePgIeuWUC@eCqZwxaSRZcS4dR3byU53y2XnADXwHlpPRlLCgVSFbYs64B/CkACbNRz41dEXBvjwiWFRY7aOfGybr01DeYkUG46Bww35bL6Do6WdcDkYUG7fxvOH3yFKfojHNpiHNIJmFbqgOFv4vUuZt1pbE3Z/IqWEeWdD4CUCUkfR1JR2aKrwwFnUDds8v6mEHlQL23@XPxOAlfsV5hOLyhXm5iQlKdwTUTM9/CYD7ZTEJNcxL2qUPqtktAtaTjw8mJknsswcvj6tZ7@GDcI63GtrjxVDbpzI80s1ww@C308RRuBT4z4v1a5ZkKR85XWL1Q/OnEL2wpNF1q4X70q8twPXT86rMq06M8tDe/RFVpcFr5D8qvHsXKmVrikfqQAT5OAX6wHuMYbITR/0XnWoY0M0495@nWxeJRqueoTcq6re8Syso6r1iL3e06YK1ka66HTl6hsGDK8sVE5TDvCcaTX2mQ33AXeDOiG3PhyTe9fEi6IQBBVt34F3NV91dC3yiEgk/EYls@ryAh0rGXqQlm1QGlW65SsulPW9fkEa3@V/C5QVPN8hHZFDo7hje9PQQ3iF7J/BfyJHxf9fHhfi88OqAhYvrrjgpye/k7HH358ZArWxx9msx8f@50nYwtL2puSx9PrnqeilPiVQNZucwVaeX6O/wc) - PCRE2 (PHP)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVtb9s2EP6eX3Fjg0ZKHSF2sS9xnWTINqBAiwJLhmGQVYCSKJsLJQokZcdw8tuzO1K248QRYJvi8Z7nuTe6sGeFNuK54bWwLS8E3K6sE/W6s7KZwZ14cMlfYtYpbv54aI2wVurGjgvFrYV6bR13soCFliV857KBKF4vuAE7uWbPP6PkU0yfo@kw@TQdHT@zMRnNpBFLQFTxENnktsutM0gWDQc2@SaamZufjeKBt/9oHfElN7pupRJl7AHaFwDXjLEourqYTpPH9CdjWXwaMwanAzg9bMCtD8lpfMXiceAFNa60iWTjoJqcjyM1uUFKrQQGzstvshFRHP8yaTqFByfDeC2rqLo8jzen/jHSiXBsfAQgK4hUH8flr/DxI6j0PJtMTthJjGb/7LlGbH3@tB4@sYFJvtrv3BXzKBQheSf9iQ89@bsRtuCtiFrcaBUWL1IDdjycNscjFscY4p3pxAUAu2B/cmVxyQbKixT4dkCFNz/h88x426oVGwAtjCgkz/G1lw8fwCEyRGTMgjVFc3zEDL8X5GV4cS8c5CtwcwGKdndudaecbJUAHcoLZ@iQ7Xuk3oU3JWFl@2ApmpDLGd05IkPUuhVuKy9IrChkiH7XwjYnDpba3AN3wJVC35wqT745gszmDuayBg4zjbs73391B7pRK5ghvdNgRK0XKLsRYDdtS@Jzk/UoqcwCTkpA0kKjPaVeYvMeMcQtdEO8gQFfuqZE@eylZKItOImec6TDJjAcrOuqigKgHODcGQfagMAECYlbhnSgf4YAKcJGATc@IGKmtfVF8oscc2fZ27wFa@bNqUf5r7MIA9gOlXxAHIV3hk@hX8D@s8X5jUqYYX/4QzsYi@F4mJYrD0O/QOt9mL7TyJqR@YCWAeSd8wAZIaSBh0MhTdHV/oDVmDfcpP1tInKvnpv8tfi9AO7Ir9CdKiEXW06UlGfomrKY6rCJB7czRExzFgdVPvU7Jb5bMn/gbWF4nnM/cvjzvp5wjBqE9NhWSQd4eemdNF31GHQW9dEUbQW@MOJ3r7LHREXWSaXeqN44UQsbiU3nWzisDor86k5sGB1SpVvszx0aXpErbHFeuA6DX23GyupaYJHCSCF4lnr4sh/gGm8E3/xF50iH0txPP87T@8miUar5KgRkbVcHiEoaS1lrMfYlBUyZnGvjUKebY2b9kAmco5KmHemI6VCb7NP9wJsBuyHXbt6jh0vCehFIIurWrRDubol/lrcSb3lDyPjql6@zSBDYsYZQS2FEialZ9SEZsRDGhni8NZSS7gIBNc2Hb1eMwRJ448IpVIP8BQ9XwA23Tr0e3kP85IAZQSwnF5SQL1@uYfT58ZJQcD36fHX1eBl2XowtWrJgSjen@56HYs7xXwKjttsSKOHoPf4f) - .NET (C#)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVZtb9s2EP6eX3FVi0ZyEzVNv9V1s25rgQHrNiz9MsgqQEm0zYQSVZKKY6T57dlzpPLixDWQiLzjPffc8e6kM3EhDs@a8xvV9sZ6OsM@VyafTOmhZPBK75RZuZSXrOmHSquaai2coy9CdXQ1ipwXHo8LoxpqoUhPvVXdkoRduqLMyK@sWTv6dFnL3isDwz2iz0pLWsw6uQ7LNMlr08gc@iSb/josFtLK5l8pGmmpCse2hemt5bhdZNl09OsO/HS9Yvw0dbMKIYjmT9XJNMuezbpB60wtUpfL74PQLk1eTyaTJMuuto9GhDT1OwGugODvEADwGggVzp1P3avZ/rzb56efXkfZ9T/Ce2k7srNxhWjbnh24bIpsnNai6xCp6vrB04w4uFGWnm6cl22uugzX03lSs6MpjfGF8/lKuL/kpQc9uiIwU89mR9loZqDvkRavu5QBZm/YHzzGXGk4iyAdEMbQgUGpzrXsln6VZh@O6OVL0nm9EvajT4@y2Ww/2c/CNT6A@g4orpdei1p@Vtb5NJknaXrybo5f/qP4Nk/KbJLNE5oc0ORnKgif55PsJDmg5MWbeffiOMmmo6cvwtcrpKmFK5u3cZd@B@PH0S7SNl@orkkzOqHkqx3kO6KE3lHyGVeGDUCvn1ilGtLr6z0uiZtvaf4q47@9@Zv81fz4xQ3f800i@l5vmB0WVtZKVNjS@HtOHr4oZWUZtQXU2V5ixblkKyvqc@mp2qAvJGmW3pu1g/aqx82a0CmODmFQblsUwUR0DWOV22AFVPDlLUJiZ0Bte@nv6EWKC04Bpb8b6bp9T2tjz0l4EijsvaTiy2TbCiDLlaeVaknQ0kB6b/ufGch0ekNLuPeGrGzNBWh3ktxQuVgRhwxSjiiFKiNOwUDKUWeCS7OWDdwCtzYd@40esBm6BvSTh5TZLdoCpFcC7lCyVmD@YDJwAJwDDCPML2NJIkFSeS6XwwBaAqAAbBpxsx0klsa4cElhUSF3Lnmat6gtg7oIKGeDAwyhHBbqEjhatAGmCgva/t3hfOQrLFEf4dA9jEM4AaYXOsDwk3i9DTNWGmtLVu/gckAV5gkfKRmhiH4E1crWQxsOOIO8Qcjyu0RUgb2w1WPyWwF8ZbvaDLqhSt75BKWqhGmRZHwPt/FAXAKxqJIssgqpv2cSqqUMB55ejKgqEVoOj5/zice4QJiP67XyPDHNPTWzGDH4LPhxF90RfKDE/5HliAlGDq9D/YT1rRGXsFUoulDCcbWT5B9@38XWYVamR33eo2HwblDiovZ4s@DI2FbOtBKXFFsK4GUR4JuxgVtMhFD89eCZhzYidD/66efJ4lZqxSYG5NzQRogFD@7xPbTmgDmTK3wTgKdfIbOhyST6qOFuhzv2tKtMtt39jcmAaqiMX43ocUi4QAJOZNv7DeC@rvFpcaowmC0jYxuWj7PIEKhYy6gNfxYgNZsxJCsvpHUxnqCNV8mzQFLL/RHKFTE4Bu98PAU28F@LOAJ@E87rx827yz8bICPA8uqCE/L@/S90/PbHB0bB@vjtycmPD1HyoG2hKaOquD091jzxixYlgBjurkBL/mxw2f8) - Java (JDK)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVNb9s4EL37VwzUApIa10jSm7fuB1ossKcemstC0QKURFtMKFEgqbgC@t@zb0jFjhPXQCKKM/Pem@EMNUy@Nf31o@oGYz25yS2tXN450y8sbcgmSfL4X7a6yPlvcXu1uri9fvuI3eJq/f6q/IvU5nKxNZY0qZ7DV843ql8viNSW1JoGq3qf5fy@uYq7WvaZzkn0DekivgBqs0lv@3RNeqOLS8Y@43zJXgmcZiIz@tXeKi@z5MaOck2UcIyVq074us3skhh0dWdUn3FSK21E47K0SC/g5MYqS9@s3qXLNF3q/CIt0zzPSWonKflb4LGmhKW/otP5YyKGQU/JknhhZa1EhVeaf2/IQxBlbCyjtYA5XyRW3EuOsqK@l56qiXwrSfPuMawbtVeDlmQGr0zv6D0CytOIIoRwYYBVnoIVMIHLW0hmMqB2g/QHeVHillOk7LuRrk897Y29J@FJaI3YCge349gKILvWU6s6ErQz2D3G/mtGMr2eaAd6b1D6zjxAdi8J1XWeQVh8ZcsZpVBlxCkYSDnqTaA0e9mAFri16Zk3MuBl7BvIT55LZtpasOhWgE7@8laQ8@N2ywlwDZwX6Gc0pkSBpMKWZR2ILwFQADaLuPkZETtjXDiksKhQO5e8rlu0lsFcBJS70QEGPS@36hdwtOgCTBUWdPo74HzlIyzRH8HpCOOQToAZhA4w/CRen8LMncbWks1ntCypGn0AKBmhiDyCamXrsQsOzqBu2OT9QyGqoF7Y6qX4kwRuOK42o26okgdOSKpKhBZJzufwlA@2SyAWVZJHVaH0RyWhW8rg8PpgRFWJMHJ4/FlPdOMGYT1u0MrjdkJ3HqSZ7YzBvkm8Xg4Cnxnxf1Y5Y0KR80rrV6qfgriFrULThRaOq7Mi//Gpi6PDqsyA/jyi4RKb0OKi9iOSn57GyplO4pDiSAG8LAJ8Mw9whxshNH89etaByy5MP@bpz8XiUerEFBNybuwixFZZx1UbkPueE@ZKtvhGQKdvUdkwZBJz1PC0g46ZzrXJKd0P3Azohsr4dkaPl4QLIkAiu8FPgLvZ44PyUzkQMjJew/JlFRkCHWsZtZFWNijNNKdk5YO0LuYTrPEo@S6Q1PF8hHZFDo7Bex@9oAb8tYhXwDfhvH45vOf4OQAVAZZXD1yQjx@/0PWH358YBevrD58///4Ud56NLSxlNBVP3nPPU90KfCWQtTscgZae3/P/AQ) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVVRb9s2EH7Pr7ipA2Qvidqkb3XdLFg2oHtogTUvg6IFlETbTChRI6k4Aor99ew7UrbjxDWQmOTdfd93xzva9uXwZOW/vbKS0jtn2vTI0pz@kkv52GWtXNPV5fVlZqWoZ6Tm72a0XiktSc@X0rsjIrUg9ROfd713M5Jt8DubsUHnp2fFfJ7ctMkMETp/l2Wn50XwiqE4gkOapNgSOTD/@e3rl6wT1slJmqfHOlu6vpy8fZP98vYkTafHaZFOszuj2gnDTkNcZ1XrOfo/snRBybXt5QeihD5Q8ofQDptkQxp9ddze3v7@5er29umfSXY85b@jm7Ps@Ob856enRHSdHpIT4oWVlRIltjR@3pAHB03YWERrDvP0KLHiXnKUFdW99FQO5FcoF5/uwppee9WhjKbzyrSOThFQ7EfkIUS0NWMV@2A5TODy1vSeyYDadNJv5UWJC06dJldGujb1tDb2noQnoTViS9RhybElQJYrTyvVkKClweku9m/Tk2n1QLht8oasbMwDZLeScC3OMwiLL20xouSqiDg5AylHrQmUZi1r0AK3Mi3zRgZs@raG/OS5ZKatBIteCdDJR28FOd8vFpwA18B5YT0Zy9dIUuHIsg7EFwDIATuJuNMDIpbGuHBJYVGidi55XbdoLYI5Dyh3vQMMWkgu1CNwtGgCTBkWtP/Z4lzyFRboj@C0g3FIJ8B0QgcY/iZe78OMncbWgs0HtJxQ2fsAUDBCHnkEVcpWfRMcnEHdcMjn20KUQb2w5Uvxewlcc1xlel1TKbeckFQWCM2TKd/DJh8cF0DMy2QaVYXS75SEbimCw@uLEWUpwsjh68d6ohs3COtxnVaeMNRmJ80sRgz2hT6eoq3AZ0b8H1WOmFDkvNL6lepNELewVWi60MJxdVDkZ5@6ODqsynTozx0aXr4BLS4q3yP5YTNWzjQSlxRHCuBFHuDrcYAbvAih@avesw5tRJh@zNOPi8Wj1IghJuRc30SIhbKOq4ZXm9acMFdyZayHTr9CZcOQScxRzdMOOmY61Cb7dF/xMqAbSuNXI3p8JFwQARLZdH4A3PVatfRNORAyMrZh@bKKDIGOtYxaSytrlGYYU7LyQeJ3IkgN1niV/BZIang@QrsiB8fgrY9eUAP@SsQn4DfhvH45vIf4OQAVAZZXD1yQjx9/pfP33z8xCtbn7y8uvn@KJ8/GFpYimvKN99jzVK0EfiWQtdtegZae99P/AQ) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXRctM6EH2mX7GYDolL29DyRgu9d@69zPB0H@gL47iMbCuxqGwZSW4I438vZyUnbdrgmSTyrvacs6tdpRCuvrdSVHRiK5pMyF5eTr6Nz@T@Znr6JuXPi/nZ6Zv5@eH9xnewqpWW9PnTlw80xpMehoxOWkoOdUL5RWUOXuD9Fx06yodBlrW5cB/OLngR9gydtJpOOkkTN7tJptOr9/P56ZDdJHl6lCZ0dExHe6wwvDo9Sq9m87O5n5/P384mg5NQ8F/7S1IyO7Szlz/OLn4kr18HKlZ0bXv5nohJh63xk9AOVhgPKtPK@0R0nV4nx8QLK0slCrzS@LwiDxCasjOP3gzu9CCx4lZylBXlrfRUrMnXkjRbH8KaXnvVoWSm88q0jk4QkO9GZCFEtBVj5btgGVzg8tb0nsmA2nTSb@VFiQtOiab/GunaiaeVsbckPAmtEVtY1S45tgDIsvZUq4YELQ2sD7FfTU@m1Wtagt4bnG5j7iC7leT6wnkGYfGFzUeUTOURJ2Mg5ag1gdKsZAVa4JamZd7IgJe@rSA/eSyZaUvBomsBOvnTW0HO94sFJ8A1cF5YT8aSRIGkgsmyDsTnAMgAO4246R4RS2NcOKSwKFA7lzyvW/TmwZ0FlO@9AwyhHRbqJ3C0aAJMERa0@2xx/uYjzNEfYdMDjEM6AaYTOsDwL/F6F2bsNPbm7N6j5ZiK3geAnBGyyCOoVLbsm7DBGdQNRrZvC1EE9cIWT8XvJHDNcaXpdUWF3HJCUpEjNEtSPodNPjDnQMyKJI2qQukflIRuycOG5wcjikKEkcPPn/XEbdwgrMd1WnlSLbpzK80sRgzeC308RVuBj5z4HlWOmFDkvNL6mepNELewVWi60MJxtVfkZz9xcXRYlcHt9ghNLWiNFhel75H8ejNWzjQShxRHCuB5FuCrcYAb3Aih@cvesw5tRJh@zNOfi8Wj1Ih1TMi5vokQC2UdV61D7itOmCtZG@uh09eobBgyiTmqeNpBx0z72mSX7n/cDOiGwvh6RI@XhAsiQCKbzq8Bd71SLX1RDoSMjNewfFpFhkDHWkatpOWbPZSO0ay8k9bFfII3HiXfBZIano/QrsjBMXjr4y6oAX8p4hXwj3BePx3effwcgIoAy6s7Lsjl5V90/m74yChYn7@7uho@RsujsYUnj65ss3vseSprgX8JZO22R6Cl5/f0Nw) - POSIX ERE (sed), tab as delimiter
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXBbts4ED03XzFQg9pO42ST3pq02cUuCvTUQ3NZyMqClGiLG0rUklRcF/r37BtSduLEFWCbmuG892Y4Q0vh60enREVzV9FkQu76evLP@Ewe76Zn72f8ebO4OHu/uDx@3PqO1rU2ir5@@f6Jxngyw5DTvKXs2GRUXFX26A3ef9Kxp2IYVFnbK//p4ooXcc/QKWdo3ima@PO7bDq9@bhYnA35XVbMTmYZnZzSyQErDG/PTmY354uLRVhcLn47nwxq5VRH8/9@KiC77N27SMJabl2vPhIx3bAzfhHGwwrjUWVb9ZiJrjOb7JR44VSphcQrjc9bCgChKTuL5M3hnh1lTtwrjnKivFeB5IZCrciw9Sms6U3QHYplu6Bt62mOgGI/Io8hoq0Yq9gHy@ECV3C2D0wG1KZTYScvSVxySjT9yyrfTgKtrbsnEUgYg1jpdLviWAmQVR2o1g0JWllYn2L/tj3Z1mxoBfpgca6NfYDsVpHvpQ8MwuKlK0aUXBcJJ2cg7am1kdKuVQVa4Ja2Zd7EgJe@rSA/ey6ZaUvBomsBOvUjOEE@9MslJ8A18EG4QNaRQoGUhsmxDsQXAMgBO024swMiVtb6eEhxIVE7n72uW/IW0Z1HlH97DxhCOyz1D@AY0UQYGRe0/@xw/uAjLNAfcdMTjEc6EaYTJsLwL/F6H2bsNPYW7D6g5ZRkHyJAwQh54hFUalf2TdzgLeoGI9t3hZBRvXDypfi9BG45rrS9qUiqHSckyQKheTbjc9jmA3MBxFxms6Qqlv5JSeyWIm54fTBCShFHDj@/1pO2cYOwHt8ZHUi36M6dNLscMXgv9PEU7QQ@c@J7VDliQpEP2phXqrdB3MJOo@liC6fVQZFfw8Sn0WFVFvfaMzS9pA1aXJShR/Kb7Vh52ygcUhopgBd5hK/GAW5wI8TmL/vAOowVcfoxT78uFo9SIzYpIe/7JkEstfNctQ65rzlhrmRtXYDOUKOyccgU5qjiaQcdMx1qk326b7gZ0A3ShnpET5eEjyJAopoubAB3u9YtfdcehIyM17h8WUWGQMc6Rq2UU/hXiaVjNKcelPMpn@hNR8l3gaKG5yO2K3LwDN6GtAtqwF@KdAX8KXwwL4f3ED8HoCLACvqBC3J9/Ttdfhg@MwrWlx9ubobPyfJsbOEpkivf7h57nspa4F8CWfvdERgV@H32Pw) - POSIX ERE (egrep), tab as delimiter

Comment: `¶` is how Retina encodes a newline in a program that is read from a single file of newline-separated parts; you can use `-m` to indicate that newlines should be literal in which case you have to provide each part as a separate file or `-e` argument.

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I had only taken a very quick look at your program after writing mine. A cursory read of its description made it look like the delimiter was tab, but it was just that your test suite converted tab to newline.

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 60 bytes

```sh
for ((c=#2;++i<$#1;))t=${1: i}&&2=${2:/${1%$t}?*$t}
((c-#2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDPbsIwDMbveQorlNIOTYNy4@@kPcJ23CUJSRvRNlWSamODZ@/sgsRll3yff45jxz@hGkyWZ4NxHrJM7SbFZj6322Sy3OR53CW/yzXYa5oWaIv1C8bTJF4PT3gwvP88KfJ8yBmjemW96htjvyFEb9sSMsZF19VnDqReKyskRYx7cdJIvVAnHUGeIVYa6hEyHr3rI2aj75tOR0KS3kMkMVVWESrbgIDSEWTciFq5FtNoggb0fXvEYsqVzgVqNarEBwPRWjQE5U0Z70RNMQmMFltSXnhJXkgp6BN0YjtvdXukdneDqHaCRqYpGEdD8vFlW3i3IWqPBKObY1yJcaQ3EeKt13b7CsXqskeItlgdDpf9HbCcGUgeq03uu01T6NBEA7PpchHABlzI45ozMC0W4bOd/VM8/AE)

Key constructs here:

- `${var:/pattern}` will replace $var by the empty string if pattern matches the full string.
- `((#var))` is zero if $var is empty.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>76</s> 62 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{s=a.size;s<b.size&&(1..s-2).any?{|i|a==b[0,i]+b[i-s,s]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/NboMwEITvfYpVDlGrAmrJsfxE6iO0N8RhlzhgxWBkG1U05NmpbbB62tlvRvasmmher/kaFxjRXeeYaP7LPnRGXhyPz@9JouP0JcFhLu8LXzDPqXqLeP1KFY91pOvHYx3hWh1wHMV8iMAJxRqOZNf6yXsKb8xZCpsbM0AzmI6BcHRPGCUn4yJGTf3ITOCk@NA6TjbQdgY63gNCKy3dI1cUjRxcxirNwC7TcLHPhEArpfbfe0H2fR0sgb13yIsdjig8dBOcDl18EhUFgEToL7YjlFGcDRdfZlOBC4n@Ptt0R24L@vuHD/DFtWHKYbt6ubsNbv0/UZv/Oll2hvS0FM6xOj2V5VJspF7/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Bracmat](https://github.com/BartJongejan/Bracmat), 54 bytes

```
(C=c w a z.!arg:(?c.?w)&@(!c:%?a (%?z&@(!w:!a % !z))))
```

This solution uses associative (string) pattern matching and expression evaluation during pattern matching. 
The associative pattern is %?a %?z, which splits the subject, !c, in two strings, neither of which is empty. (The % prefix ensures that a pattern variable does not accept a neutral element, i.e. an empty string, in the case of string pattern matching.)
The expression that is evaluated during pattern matching is @(!w:!a % !z). This happens to be another associative string pattern matching operation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU9ha8IwEP2c/IorWE1hCOq34qzDbSAbDNR925dLG9NgmpY0UhX/e3fVwL337h33kkiPeYWh78XmNYcOEG7TCL1ORZZPsy4Zr0WUp3GGIOLsNnRdGiHEEN0SOn1X2olYC63CRLShMO5lf9glaRZfZvAXgHiewBjqcxgJsRmJ6DKbRk/v52v7TnX/fNt@/@4@EqAZDLOkx6axV0boVW5Q2iv3eFKM3npSAeQVQqnAksWDp2gW/LlqVODSG6eZJE@XAUpT0X907TQ/os1rx4haBaTOrqAVruu6VeyBkhJabrFSTA7IG7SKDQBUXDKJXnKUEhlK5EdvlCvYk/jR1hhY7fihMw72pg3KM9ID8xzpjg22gWKWyzXMF/cVIzFfZNl99Wj/AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
.œÅΔćìθQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkw63nphxpP7zm3I7A//8TCwqKUpMzE5NyKrmA7JxKAA)

Outputs a non-negative number if it is a circumfix, -1 otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 70 bytes

```
procedure f(a,b)
return(1<*a<*b&a==b[1:i:=2to*a]||b[i-1-*a:0]&1)|0
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLBbsIwDIbvPIXVA2orkCi7oQKT9gjbDXGwSygRbVK5iRBS35054TI1y8W/7c@R7UQ31rxeA9tGXTwruOa4omLBynk2eVWXWJe0xP2eTtVO7/ZbZ0s8TxOd9Lpal7jbnJdVMW0Wylz@XNOjNnmxADkP1k7l1zzDYeie2QqCYNVoJHGLGcR4V4FhbO7KAT3B3RR0ITpHHVvvAuvYD71yCUCsTRsAErK9ObjpHhBaK9E5e8VONhFgUaMCcby5sO8TsrV2jC1GQb4fxoTpsI8IRTHPDtjFbLAQdNJ4rEWmJINEGFcoJhmBtTxCHOGtEqCzGBcmg85z2SpLYj8PbeBbj05xqBI3yjnW4HsfXzi6f4ap60/YfkyHgIjefhyP0@EdETR8m18)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```ruby
->a,b{a+b=~/^(.+)(.+)(?=#{b}$)\1.+\2$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BboMwEETv/YpVkkMj0kRNrgEq9RPaW5NKu8SAFcDIGFUoSX@drhesHmBn34zsse1pGPN4fElwQzeMKP7dfT9vo7V8aby80WO1Pr1uo9N@tXuMLeRfC2zbalhswAurMo3E6/lJPItX5S2L2VU5oAFcqaDydE44a3rnI872datc4GR1U3hOHChKB6WuAaEwTOdIjlVmGp9h1SngpW8ufEwIFMZ0cr0I4vO7YFVYi0MiZthiJdBP8Dp0kSRaCgCJUF7MI5SxWjUXKTOpwCuD8j5uOiO/Bf35oxv40J1T1mNeRc5uhlP/d@zcf53j8Q32h3viHdb7Q5rek4mEftyOf8TzPP4B)

#### How

Simple regex: if a+b can be split in 5 parts ABCDE where A==C and B==E, and b=CDE, then a is a circumfix of b.

Thanks benrg for pointing out a problem with the first solution (and saving 1 byte).

Comment: I really like this.

Comment: This fails on inputs like "aa","aabaa" because it finds an incorrect solution and rejects it without backtracking to look for another one. I don't know Ruby, but could you do something like `/^(.+)(.+)(?=\Q$b\E$)\1.+\2$/`? Then you wouldn't need the final test.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>72</del> <del>71</del> 62 bytes

```hs
\a b->or[a==take i b++drop j b|j<-[2..length b-1],i<-[1..j-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVLBbuIwEL3nK0ZpDyBIpNLbCuhWdLeXalWpuydAq3FiEoNjR2NHXbTst9OxWZL64jfvPY3f2K7RHaTW57/ZDbw8/nj@9fj8DVavr3CT/UsS1bSWPDyhx/y71SUKLWG0s/R7DFkGnZMlWKOPoAz4WoKXzkONZKRzUzDWX4XCNq30ylSMSsmN3UpR0TU79QcWsDlvEES2tLTGxcLjQYICMZmUZFvYgzjt59l6ludamsrX7LzbThVTd3m@Z7w9h3NX6KTjZusEeI1SbFt9TKcQAMlCcfZjOp7@V4kPCSJhcZAexDHG1IHtPZ5s54PJUxfiD4ogHiUogi1VzTOrBhAqy2xv2qEurAkuRi7cgelMya0GS2WtizEiEHyKG0SNTdREBD3doo502CHgIVV0I4mBQiEw3gFvQzBS0pQx2AUNirYYJ@bcPRnqofr5zk/6ppyXFAQuI@z1Ai8T8XP4z@Hm868wuz8tg8Z4dv/wcFpemPE2SRrktgsIXwuG17yFzbWAbAmljc3azr95ejEsu9q@936YTCD9AmnYozDqTNER8ff89N2u7vH5Aw)

- -1 byte by moving `l a<l b` into the list comprehension, where it only needs a `,` rather than an `&&`
- -9 bytes from [benrg's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194929/is-it-a-circumfix/194964?noredirect=1#comment464043_194964)

Comment: `\a b->or[a==take i b++drop j b|j<-[2..length b-1],i<-[1..j-1]]` saves 9 bytes.

Comment: @benrg applied, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
f=lambda c,s,i=1:i<len(c)<len(s)and(c==s[:i]+s[i-len(c):])|f(c,s,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBbsMgDL3vK6zuEtTs0PYWNW2lfcJ2q3owhCSoFCKgmir13zPjaFLZyc/vPYNtmB5p9G43z31r8SY7BFXH2rSbxuytdpUSHKJA11WqbeO5MZd1PJuPRW0u4tlXXLPeiLn3IR8AxkH1Vq1wmuxjVUMGQSuDklJRwzukcNdkCHjVWQ@orjqBfEAaNdjMvtpS8PeUfZTfJp0WsUcbsyqDcUNWJdmGMcFoboAweGILI0XlXXYyA5TcXUdHlrbB@8hdMZB0YywNtCnWJYNCmtCylCNk/DqG5CIMsqxBKZGXRKHsNxjtOu53QaVqPfJSaKRCyFzJfP/Qg3yZmHTIIqUMC4/CZehPjMn@m2q/P8F29zxknfB2dzw@Dwsj/sYTDUz0EKni7yDqoKdAH2SJUYj5Fw)

*-2 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)*

Answer (score 3):

## Curry, 28 bytes

*Tested to work in both [PAKCS](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/) and [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/)*

```
f(a:b++c:d)(a:b++_:_++c:d)=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NI9EqSVs72SpFE8KKt4qHcG0N/@cmZuYpWFkpBBSl5pSmpOp5@itoaHKBRW0VCooy80oUVBTSFJTS8tOVgGQRkPoPAA)

This returns `1` if the first argument is a circumfix and nothing otherwise.  In cases where there are multiple ways the string could be a circumfix it will return `1` multiple times i.e. it is non-deterministic but always gives `1`.  I think this is fine.

The program is basically just a pattern match checking that the first input is made up of two non-empty strings and that the second is made of the same two strings with another non-empty string between them.

This uses two pattern matching features available to Curry not present in Haskell.  The first is `++` patterns, and the second is pattern variables.  e.g. we require the two `a`s to be *the same `a`*.

This allows it to beat out [the Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194964/56656) handily.

### Testing

TIO has a limited ability to test things like this.  Paste the following to [smap](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?new/curry) and run in `PAKCS 2.2.0` for better testing abilities:

```
import Control.SetFunctions


f(a:b++c:d)(a:b++_:_++c:d)=1

-- Helper to run tests
helper :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
helper x y =
  not $ isEmpty $ set0 $ f x y
  
main =
  [ helper "fog" "frog"
  , helper "apply" "appreciably"
  , helper "rake" "racket by the lake"
  , helper "trout" "trumpet"
  , helper "bring" "brought him a gong"
  , helper "falcon" "false conundrum"
  , helper "goose" "goosebumps"
  ]
```

This test handler will not work in KiCS2 or at least not on the version used by smap.  But the function itself does if you want to manually test it.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>b=>[...a].some((_,i)=>b[l=a.length]&&a==b.slice(0,l-i)+b.slice(-i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFBbsIwEEX3nMLqAhIVrAq2JFSq1AuUXYqqcRgSl4kd2U4rJO6e2oZKrZzV/PnzZP@xP@ELbG1k71ZKH3E8FSMUpSjKinMOB251h1n2sZS5dysqgBOqxrWH@RyKQnBLssbsaUkrmT/@tl7nY62V1YScdJMtqr0ZXHs5LPLZX/@UPUDf0@Uhj8JgLUGENsEMnDFQBuozOiYuzLXIKLoJ3ANFOFQWdYJst89svbmWAfN6vdntruXdyWf/6MW7ql6B7FR6Z/TgwhnODF2PbuImYaRqAiI827SOtbJjwBod3IQ@AXkn4F5ZZL4Z1NEfPsE2Wtu4ZxTCB7ATFEEXIXETab44BCMmZiAExL8JJc1qJKpjzHpXKUIa4vuEnZJpGEzY@2@p2Ju0Dk0gfHuTCVjDbf8XsC7@8vgD)

Comment: Eventually you can avoid returning `undefined` moving the first test inside `some`

Comment: @edc65 Good idea. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

```
s=>t=>[...s].some((x,i)=>t[l=s.length]&&i&&s==t.slice(0,i)+t.slice(i-l))
```

Return true if

- the second string is longer than the first
- there is a position to split the first string in 2 parts, such as the second string starts with the left part and ends with the right part

**Test**

```js
z=`"apply", "appreciably" -> true
    "app]reciab[ly"
"rake", "racket by the lake" -> true
    multiple options - "r]acket by the l[ake" and "ra]cket by the la[ke"
"trout", "trumpet" -> false
    Doesn't work at all
"bring", "brought him a gong" -> false
    You only get to remove one substring - "br]ought h[i]m a go[ng" is not allowed
"falcon", "false conundrum" -> false
    You can't have extra stuff at the start or end either - "fal]se [con(undrum)" is not allowed
"goose", "goosebumps" -> false
    "goose]bumps[" is just a prefix
"lame", "blame" -> false
    And "]b[lame" is just a suffix
"pale", "pale ale" -> true
    "pale] ale[" is just a prefix, but "pal]e al[e" is a circumfix, so this is allowed
"b", "barb" -> false
    This could be a prefix ("b]arb[") or a suffix ("]bar[b"), but not a circumfix - "b]ar[b" is not allowed
"abba", "aba" -> false
    "abba" can be split into a prefix of "aba" ("ab") and a suffix of "aba" ("ba"), but "abba" is still not a circumfix of "aba"
"friend", "friend" -> false
    It's only a proper circumfix if you actually remove something - "fri][end" doesn't make the cut
"float", "on" -> false
    You may not assume the first input will be shorter than the second one
"", "" -> false
    One or both input strings may be empty
"Twin Sister", "Twister" -> false
    Inputs are ordered - you may reverse the order, but there must be a consistent ordering
"case", "Castle" -> false
    Inputs are case sensitive
"<<@ 23|>", "<<@23??|> 23|>" -> true
    "<<@]23??|>[ 23|>", not all characters will be letters)`

f=s=>t=>[...s].some((x,i)=>t[l=s.length]&&i&&s==t.slice(0,i)+t.slice(i-l))

z.split('\n').forEach((s,i)=>{
    var m = s.match(/"([^"]*)", "([^"]*)" -> (true|false)/)
    if (m) {
        console.log(`"${m[1]}" "${m[2]}" should be ${m[3]} and is ${f(m[1])(m[2])}`)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 104 bytes

```
e([],_).
e([H|T],[H|U]):-e(T,U).
e(L,[_|U]):-e(L,U).
f(X,Y):-string_chars(X,A),string_chars(Y,B),e(A,B).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYy9CoNAEIT7PMVhdQerD5AmmCqFpUJERE5Zf9DEY10JQt79sgoWaXZ2vhnG0TzNXbh8Bu9RFyVUJrrI8/imJcjNSnMNUaeQHTyBojpZcrBWPyEXvzAN765qekuLoNjAH8nhbgB1LBL5W9jqwDo3bQHsStgMthYne0dGdsQAlGgzIqt6U9yjmnZ6VpjmlfcO0/pyyBL4Hw)

Comment: [-21 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYo7C4MwGEV3f0Vw8pHH7lJ06uCoYBCRKFGDtoYYKUL/e/qltMu93HOuNvu2z@R4KefajvU0aO/vqmOQdZeRitU0KFnbf1fpV5PmGTmsUc@5HxdhjqjBeQw84RkBiXla4JwV1E1geAww4TS4kSkKhdbbFWLfRo5KDLDinzNilSFG0OMqLRouZBeJNk//F2v20/qPNedDSwvCfQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 46 bytes

```java
a->b->(a+"\0"+b).matches("(.+)(.+)\0\\1.+\\2")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLBbtswDL3nKwgBAewlEdL0tqbugAG7DRiQ3eoeKFt2lNiWIckZgtbfnlGyu0E5GHzkeyKfJZ7wgptTeb6pttfGwYlyPjjV8GroCqd0x788LYoGrYWfqDp4XwD0g2hUAdaho3DRqoSWuOTgjOrq1zdAU9s0SAF@zH32E7v@ZWSpCnRyLmQZVPB8w00mNlmCK5Zv2UqkvEVXHKVNWMJXqf/ybZ4/8FWe71h6ewq9PwfSSCets/A8DwV4B1bpmq1ZZSjAuP5fx75vrmwdgJGFQkFppDB4ll5gsDhLB@IK7iih8dVI54wenBc6M7S9dDErvDnPCpLVRwdH1QJCrbs7QxU2he68kpCVQMnQldQyltVa22ArAEETbSxosA28CCCiemwC5SN4HDsNp9CIu4sSAsM9UYgNGyW7MhieUMw2GsOt0D9FhK/Fld9/aKUOyjppPElpgJGmwOmvv6N198b3@2@we/zIPE949/jy8pFNFRiDbJw2pdImuaAJa/J1Wpb0364crjS15fSWvKc3c1XCcra0OXWdImwyWNqlfyJ/9HX7NoMHAhUPC5XMTMo9SGY6Taf53sy4GG9/AQ)

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)
- -2 bytes thanks to [Sara J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85386/sara-j)
- The 46 bytes solution (-86 bytes) is actually the full implementation in Java of [deadcode's regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197425/16236) (which incidentally also contains a Java solution, but only to demonstrate the regex).

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by doing `return r` instead of `return r>0` at the end.

Comment: @SaraJ Indeed, I thought it was true/false because of the examples in the challenge. The output format is nice for once ;-)

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize/remember you could do a regex match in Java without a lot of boilerplate. I suppose I'll keep the boilerplated version in my TIO testbed though, since otherwise it has to compile the regex each time it's called, right?

Comment: @Deadcode Yes, Java is boilerplate, but sometimes not as boilerplate as one might thing :-) The JVM keeps a cache of the last 8 regex (number to verify) that it compiled so no need to worry (too much) about performances, therefore you may shrink your version safely.

Comment: I remember now why I didn't use it. It matches the whole string, which would conflict with my format for pure regexes (which have anchors). It's great for golfing Java functions/programs that use regexes, though! Like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66197/is-it-a-pangram/197570#197570).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
#2/.{p__,__,s__}/;{p,s}==#->0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZBBasMwEEX3OYWIISu3Ls6yiWPIBQrtrhQzcmRbRLaEJFOC47O7MyMKAv15f6T50ghxUCNE3cLWnbesLF4X1zQ5rtA0a/G@uDys53P2Ur0dtg@vp/iNuqvr6wAe2qh8qLOfQ1Evu2UPzpnHPhckvGo1SCzXHB0Pd0UGHrmrKORD4FxhiLIfvZ0jNUQ/j07FRCXO64lKtPshikGPAkRvkXJDB6a1E3WgCkpgMU83vCLZvbWBx7KQeHNIhoGRuWTByIFhRLsgnRJwF3iZSpAS@H24pQBeq@nGAZJK1Fjg12A2BqST@vrVk/jUAT@OIJYs2Wshpb1CiP8BTqdalMdnRRx1ebxcnlUi627d/gA)

Takes two lists of characters as input. Returns `0` if the first string is a circumfix of the second, or the second string otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous infix function. Takes strings 1 and 2 as left and right arguments. Requires `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
{(⊂⍺)∊∊¨↑∘⍵¨¨(1↓⍳≢⍺)-⊂0,~/≢¨⍺⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/BasJAFEX3@YrZjYVKrW5FC27qqlD9gTdxjMExCZORIrVdtCBWiLQUoeuu3Lko3bjMp8yPpDczhSFz73k3772hTDUnK1JpVNn9YXhnN@@t6rFhdy@2OF/Y7Q6nPNrNh91@2eK3PJbHxrXdfNrix75915kmsq3L5ytYBIszUk/VFH1ssfctd6/lqVO32B9G9wN8x7fDUcUpy9SKsymrlZZhTAI@4Jrm0mFN4VwaJlbMzCRTNQ640enSuLLRy0UmDZjQcRI5JlCNZobN4gUjFqXAAZ@SCtPE1SFzyeCWyQS/oxilae7HOSXQMwdWtPBUOBXwjJQHtWC1wVyfIC1gSAjyr8GNoTqWycQP9RJMpeR3xzoBdwr3@CFO2CjOjdQOwTsd8JD@dxtQbtzIbveGtTvrnqMw7U6/v@559Ac)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; `⍺` and `⍵` are is strings 1 and 2:

`⍺⍵` strings 1 and 2

`≢¨` length of each

`~/` remove elements from the first that are in the second (gives empty list if same length)

`0,` prepend zero

`⊂` enclose to treat as a whole

`(`…`)-` subtract that from the following:

`≢⍺` length of string 1

`⍳` indices zero through that

`1↓` drop the first one (the zero)

This gives us the head-tail pairs to try.

`¨¨` for element of each of the head-tail pairs:

`↑∘⍵` take that many characters from string 2 (from the end if negative)

`∊¨` **ϵ**nlist (flatten) each

`(`…`)∊` is the following an **ϵ**lement of that?

`⊂⍺` the entire string 1

Comment: This appears to have a false positive for `"abba", "aba"`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>73</s> 77 bytes

```perl
sub f{(grep$_[1]=~/^@{[$_[0]=~s|.{$_}|\Q$&\E.+|r]}$/,1..length($_[0])-1)?1:0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VdNb@M2EL37VwwEoZa2irzOopd8OAm6PfSwKIrmUiiqQcmUzY0kqiSV2IjTv57OkPLXrrNAN9sk60My4pDDN0@Pj3bDVfnTw4NuMyjugqnijT9OhunpP4O/zu8SjN9irJfxnT@@X1797v9w9Uv841Kl9/4gGsZxyeupmQV2XngwDM@GR2/vH1rN4ZJrc3T0QSoOBkN9OjocHvcKqYKKNcnAC@I3Z6EXXek3XYjRwQgCo1q@LFipeYgjmAoHaaSbUpjBVT2IPkpR9/vRyfuLy4tReNcD/FSLwNfDyNeHkc/nTeSbuQlPz/3xsU3T2Cn9Af439Kl@n2C6pNBBsVodbi0/7t33xmPaZTyG7@nT81jTlAsvAqBI8VywDJ9XeeSYKACXTl0@2ZrwQqgVu@YEGjDKr7mBbAFmxqGk8S3UVVsa0ZQcZGOErDUc4Ip0d0li17B6QsXS3WoJpb4ZaqNkayzXCK9quNmpjaitkgHeS67rvoFbqa6BGWBl@YJcZ0rUU4s6Q/zTmYGZqIDBVOLwFuo/ZQuyLhcwRQaNBMUreYPM1xzQMLShMsR/ptKuTCJSVyihSkJDLW2z8pZPnooaQeWyRtieg4cPbT1B2r1drgl1zojtGUO0fG4UA23aoiDmSQXaMGVAKuAoES5wSFEbuD7FAgkWDlzl8Kk99LyplNoK20UZqkR7exTi0qnNJ3bbj63GfQGPcCHmz6yQklXdacxsuJvfoL6gM5aif9hJG9Aa2X5m0Ii6YWWHmiKgp13UK@ejdEr5PUxHkLXGTkmpROL6YpALlbeVnaAlyggHafyp2sbTaCFbrpnKPjWnDdeXtGUu23ICGd8II/CyFNclXkiKXlMf4GthKsm80DVkRbxpwh7b1E74GonjLZNlzHHNMIBHUbuJdCAJtb3IQdRoJusGZNHVCPAfdkG@vW5jK4l/u166mohbG4FO@mlv60Wfe4gSeOath7joEdS/mr521kcwZYMGsSkvCligx7DctMjZYmWLWlYcZeEsEcunid1g0ll/hZeSdZ8cO/iPzldK5m4Z9D94nGtyvootHB9at5XbsBBKE@kNbnxLfNGLmEllsCszwxdjPZGj7U2st3@j07iSNXj7LtwN6t9wS1RuJs2sA@luFm17Qay8asziuTzk8lbU8IfQSA7JBB9t@LlCCCmef0XgJ1zhwTmwsiDQit9wpR37Nut0SxcNx28w@DbsCUbGNZWvjZtF2vk61Dlzl0xH@M9Mmy3z24ualuBbRwRG3PAX@R5ycnIOh@@WI4ecHg/fnZ0tR25w27AxlbpcslrRWRbkM4bfGPEd6bW4S27oOfx/UMf4IWmwetEp1dur69f1q2CFOo7nGOw5jR3VrxV1/F2hnn8B9utVyPwLEtmgZhrwZ/z@G/S5Pw//Ag)

Comment: Fails on `"....", "any string"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7ZHBbsIwDIbvfQqritaEhXYF7QK0BWnX3bgBiwpyoVNouyRoTG336l3CNmkPsf9gffZvO5HcoJKPw6AveyhaelTYELGJd8ln9LJsN5YfLOsubInoO3IX3ndq15OIx2EosTqaE731sHHMsnj20A8XjbBGbWaz51ohGIs6SeO5V9SKnvNmE/k0HGXM51s9@kFL4xSoURfsilxqZLZiLRbtuG5kaaJtFfHXuqyCgC@eVutVyloPrM4flOiYEz3hBK8NJ@ZqWLIkYn6zXS1xAfANArc/cL/8NktNi99p9md87vWeEO4VIeBfVp4fWvncsb9YLCfTLOtSmEy71Ad7udvNrEer2kAuJRxOucoPBpWG99LmewSJxuVs@AI "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: This should be one of the tests. Corrected for this now, 4 more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 7 bytes

```
≠;sᵃN,=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZCxTsQwEERF669YbX1pcg0Sxx0SPQ10iGKd8yVWEjuyHaGTrqPiG2hSgIQELT9DB1_COKHxzL6RPSu_vDvT-l6SfN5z0fOKuDD8ML2N6VCcf_w-Txfx5-vpZnX5GnUV__n0fVayDEN3ZMoaTGVFY1IcpDWAQarWJNJHSo2hLkPFKfgxIUxh7AeTQHSwrgbRSOomUWN7Eqo9oOKDdJV3SGGiIfjR7XEVUe19zDWzarwWATvpM9OzKh6ky2MWyhZtOZWgYUVrybvjRFGwxu1z0WJAOi95U9QrhuK8e7SObm1MJgBgmp3iSuZNriWmuWSzuaJyfdqCwZbr3e60XcDyd38)

```
≠;sᵃN,=
≠           Check that the two inputs are not equal
 ;          Split the second input into two parts
  s         Take a suffix of the second part
   ᵃN       Check that both the first part and the suffix are non-empty
     ,      Join the first part and the suffix
      =     Check that the result is equal to the first input
```